# 404 - spine not found

Tags: discussion, offensive

Recently, I've been noticing a certain trend here on meta:

*People seem to become increasingly scared of possibly offending someone.*

Some examples:

---

One of the suggested questions for the 2016 survey asked what, and how much alcohol the user consumes, if any.
In response, someone that chose not to consume any alcohol said:

> I don't drink by choice, not as a result of religion or whatever the other usual reasons, and I'm sick of being bombarded with it everywhere I go.

To which a **♦ mod** replied:

> This doesn't seem like it should offend anyone, but the comments here & votes suggest it might. It's not up to me to decide what's offensive; we can only acknowledge that and try to address it, in this case by finding language for this survey question & answers that plays nice.

---

One of the candidates for moderator made a *"My eyes are up here"* joke on chat. In his moderator questionnaire answer, that was brought up like this:

> How will you handle sexist remarks as a moderator, while making derogatory comments like *"can you make a women's version that says, "My eyes are up here"?"* in chat?

---

<sup>(There's been a few more cases like this, but I think you get the point.)</sup>

In these examples, comments or suggestions are criticized just because they *might* offend someone.

So what?

SO can't possibly strive to please everyone.
Besides, the more we try not to offend anyone, the more reasons users will find to feel offended.

What happened? Since when are we on a path to abandon common sense and a sense of humor for the fear of possibly hurting someone's feelings?

This is just my observation, but *if* we are going out of our way not to offend someone, are we really doing the site a favor, or is it a lost battle?

Comment: I realize this may come across as a bit of a rant. I'm sorry if that offends anyone ;-)

Comment: I am **very** interested in this as well. I notice the trend on the internet alone, especially amongst teens, and not at all in real life - while having a quite diverse and broad group of peers. The being offended by "nothing" and the "fear" of offending others, I mean. I also wonder if it's constrained to the US. And yes, I've removed my comment that triggered the ♦ mod reply in that topic (almost immediately after posting), as I did not want to hold this discussion there.

Comment: The most interesting part of the drinking question would be to see whether peoples' answers change before and after being elected SO mod.

Comment: And how that change affects their judgement as moderator, @BilltheLizard ;-)

Comment: Unlike CodeCaster, I have actually seen a recent trend of the same thing in my local area, so it could partially be a regional thing that's just translating onto the internet. (Just a theory.) While most of the stuff I see about this doesn't offend me (even as a woman, the one from the questionnaire just seems like a poor joke comment to me. I'd just roll my eyes and laugh a little if someone made that comment sitting next to me.) I can usually at least see where someone who _is_ offended is coming from. Doesn't mean I agree with them, of course.

Comment: Also, off-topic, but I very much like your title. :)

Comment: *"the more we try not to offend anyone, the more reasons users will find to feel offended"* - I'm not convinced by that. *"Since when are we on a path to abandon common sense and a sense of humor for the fear of possibly hurting someone's feelings?"* - since the growing realisation that the culture around activities can exclude people from them, whether or not that's the intention? *"going out of our way not to offend someone"* sounds like an odd way to write *"empathise"*.

Comment: So, not considering something "Offensive" is a lack of empathy? I disagree. Sorry, but imo, exactly that attitude is the problem. Sure, empathy is crucial as a human being, but that doesn't mean anything that could possibly offend _someone_ should be removed.

Comment: @Kendra can you please give me a concrete example of a change you saw regarding offending people?

Comment: @Cerbrus *"not considering something "Offensive" is a lack of empathy?"* - no, but not understanding when and why someone else might consider it offensive certainly is. If people are telling you they're offended by something, your first response probably shouldn't be, effectively, *"you're wrong to be offended"*. *"that doesn't mean anything that could possibly offend someone should be removed"* - I'm not saying that it should.

Comment: It should be _"Why are you offended?"_, sure. But the examples I've shown are about actively avoiding offending that person. They're talking about actually changing the message, instead of figuring out why it's considered offensive.

Comment: @Cerbrus in your first example, the commenter literally included that information as well. I'm not directly offended by the question, but I can certainly understand how the implicit assumptions made in asking it could grate on people who spend a lot of their time feeling like they have to explain why they don't want a drink (or, after a few occasions like that, why they don't want to come out and socialise at all).

Comment: @jonrsharpe: The alcohol question has "none" as possible answer. It doesn't assume alcohol consumption. (I probably should've mentioned that). At parties, I'm usually the guy that doesn't drink, myself. In this specific example, I really don't see the big deal.

Comment: @CodeCaster Well, there was a long (and fought against) discussion where I work about not having a prize raffle at the Christmas party anymore because one of the prizes was a "gag gift" that was a barbie one year, and the employee who got it not only got offended that he won it (on a _raffle_ as in _anyone in the room_ could've won it) but I believe he also threatened a harassment charge over it. All that over a gag gift won out of sheer (un)luck. That's just an example. (I think the only reason the change didn't actually occur is that the charge wasn't actually made.)

Comment: @Kendra I really don't know what to say about that without offending anyone, but thanks for sharing it.

Comment: @CodeCaster It has at least gotten rid of gag gifts in the raffle, which is kinda sad. They were funny! But at least the party is still fun. :)

Comment: @Kendra if you don't find it offensive, I'll work with Stack to have them send you a barbie every X-mas, so you at least have a gag gift ;) (but SERIOUSLY.... HARASSMENT charge because of luck??!... man, some people really push it)

Comment: @Patrice I wouldn't find it offensive at all! I may never have liked barbies growing up, but I at least know how to donate new toys to kids that need them rather than complain. ;) (Yup. Just goes to show how one overly sensitive person can (nearly) ruin things for everyone.)

Comment: I think people need to watch more South Park. Especially the "insecurity" and "safe space" episodes.

Comment: *People seem to become increasingly scared of possibly offending someone.* That's why I'm here--to bring balance to the universe of Meta.

Comment: @Will still no funding for the eyeball Dremel? I was _sure_ that thing was going to catch on. Folks, don't let Will scare you _too_ much, he did reach a lot of people that went on to be great contributors to the site. They have to sit down in order to be fingerprinted, but they did become great contributors to the site.

Comment: @TimPost no need to fund the eyeball dremel.  That's a *real, in use today, medical device.*  It's used to abrade the surface of the eye so foreign bodies can be removed. And if your eyes aren't watering right now, you are a robot.

Comment: @TimPost how many of these great contributors did Will have to file a restraining order against? ;)

Comment: It's a matter of perspective - if a comment is made that will _knowingly_ offend someone then that is absolutely wrong. If a comment is made with no intention to cause offence, and someone does in fact become offended - then that's not being derogatory or offensive in my eyes.

Comment: @MacroMan: True, but just saying _"I didn't mean to offend anyone"_ doesn't suddenly make a comment harmless.

Comment: @cerbus absolutely - but we all learn from trial and error. If the person says _"I didn't mean to offend anyone"_ and genuinely means it - then they won't do it again, I don't think it's fair to chastise someone for something they were genuinely unaware of.

Comment: @Codecaster *"I think people need to watch more South Park. Especially the "insecurity" and "safe space" episodes. "* - that is an answer in itself really. You can design a playlist of South Park episodes that when watched in order act like a sort of societal retardation intervention. The episode about the war on gluten and the food pyramid... I was so sad that only a satirical animation show with a history of shock value seasons actually gets it.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Eggshells are not a suitable foundation on which to build. If everyone is uncomfortable, nothing is pleasant. I agree with that premise, but I think you might be unwittingly making a very wide assumption here:

> People seem to become increasingly scared of possibly offending someone.

I'm not certain that scared is the best description; I have also seen people being more careful, which is a pleasant reminder that most people would opt not to make someone uncomfortable if given the choice. Could it be that what you're seeing is simply an artifact of people being aware of choices that might have eluded them previously?

The unfortunate path of learning what isn't 'trivially' objectionable to someone is realizing the extent that you made them feel belittled, unwelcome or uncomfortable through something that you said. You often learn this in retrospect, as an epiphany that hits you while you witness something else. You then actively avoid that which you may have once dismissed by suggesting that someone might benefit from a thicker skin.

In short, you don't know what hurts until you realize how much it hurt someone. Compounding this is the fact that many people that are made to feel marginalized in some manner don't speak up about it, because why would they if common wisdom involves thicker skins and stronger spines? Thus, it perpetuates.

This doesn't mean that we have to be on eggshells, or at odds at all. But we do need to consider that giving people a safe space to say '*that really made me feel bad and I wish you wouldn't say that*' is part of what we mean by being here to learn from one another. If people feel safe enough to speak up, and that they won't be immediately invalidated if they do, then we're one step closer to a place where everyone feels welcome.

Be nice when you tell someone that they crossed a line. Be nice, and be open, if someone suggests that you have. Learn from each other. That's all we ask.

Comment: "Eggshells are not a suitable foundation on which to build." I'm glad we don't have any egg-laying animals around that could take offense to this statement. Otherwise we'd have to go out of our way to avoid using this metaphor in the future.

Comment: @BoltClock what about [bluefeet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) and [matt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/444991/matt)?

Comment: @ryanyuyu: Shhh, they haven't seen this question yet.

Comment: I've seen it @BoltClock and you are walking the line...

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree with this answer. We need to be aware though for people who _proactively feel offended for others_ (i.e. making a problem where there isn't, because they _think_ someone _might_ be offended by something, I'm not talking about people who are genuinely coming out on behalf of others), and for the increasing number of trolls on the web (*kin) who engage in the "social justice warrior" scheme.

Comment: @CodeCaster I try to remain receptive to people that just want to share something that they know, like "You might really make someone feel bad that way, and here's why" to the point that I don't always _immediately_ identify people that are so lost in the reason that they're picking a fight that they don't even remember why they're doing it. I suggest erring on assuming _most_ people are just trying to help, even if they need some good feedback on how they're going about it, as this makes the truly lost-and-combative folks easier to spot.

Comment: You can generally spot such trolls by their blatantly unconstructive tone, @CodeCaster. As with most low-effort trolls.

Comment: @BoltClock It IS good we don't have any egg-laying animals around. I'll note though that if you'd kept a certain _other_ CM-crusader for an icon, we'd be having an entirely different discussion right now....

Answer (score 21):

> Since when are we on a path to abandon common sense and a sense of humor for the fear of possibly hurting someone's feelings?

Actually you are absolutely correct that users don't need to go out of their way to avoid stepping on toes.  The current [Be Nice policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice), if anything, endorses your view:

> Be welcoming and patient, especially with those who may not know everything you do. Oh, and bring your sense of humor.... In summary, have fun, and be good to each other.

The rest of the policy outlines guidelines for being polite and respecting other users, but it does not claim you have to be a saint.  Just that you should have some minimum level of respect for your fellow users, which most people in the SO community have.  Wrongly branding someone as "intolerant/racist/sexist/etc" is, well, offensive and even actively harmful to their (actual) web reputation.  So **users also need to be careful in accusing other users of malicious intent**, and that includes not trolling other users with frivolous and premature "this might offend someone" ivory tower standards.

Clearly rude material has no place on SO, but *maybe, possibly off-color* content doesn't need to be overmoderated.  IMO, as long as users make an honest attempt to be polite and professional, any lingering "offensive" content can just be edited or removed as necessary.  Edits, comments, and comment flags are usually sufficient in this regard.

Comment: Well said! Couldn't have analyzed it better myself. :)

Comment: Why humor? I thought we hated fun! (jk jk)

Comment: Except then you end up being the one accused of violating this policy when someone takes offense to something that is otherwise generally not a big deal. *Edit* rereading the third paragraph it specifically accounts for that sort of thing.

Comment: @BoltClock in those situations, my opinion is that polite comments notifying the user once the actual offense has occurred is the way to go.  Then the content can be removed as necessary.  Or even just a simple edit or "Not constructive" comment flag.  No harm no foul.  And of course, if the situation escalates, then it's time for a moderator flag.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there are, and always will be, people who go through life trying to find fault with others. These are the people for whom the phrase "offence is taken, not given" was coined. They're not trolls because their offence is not false; they really believe that the world is out to get them. In this respect they're worse than trolls, because a troll generally stops at some stage once s/he has got enough of a rise out of his/her audience.

There's nothing you can do about these kinds of people, except ignore them. Engaging with them is a waste of time because they're not willing to be reasoned with. (In this they're rather like the religious fundamentalists they so often claim to be the polar opposite of.)

Ultimately it's about the difference about being constantly offensive versus a few off-the-cuff comments. The former are not and should not be welcome on Stack Overflow, the latter are only human. Everyone says something insensitive every now and again, but that doesn't mean we should be pre-emptively censoring in case that one person is "triggered".

Comment: _"Everyone says something insensitive every now and again, but that doesn't mean we should be pre-emptively censoring in case that one person is "triggered"."_ This sums up my point of view pretty well.

Comment: Being brush and abrasive is one thing - everyone has bad days. Using what someone _is_, or _something about them_ in a manner that demeans, marginalizes or ridicules them ***is*** something that polite people should endeavor to avoid, and appreciate being called out on if they inadvertently do it.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion it's a disturbing trend on the internet as a whole, striving to and going to great lengths as to not offend anyone. I'm fine with taking extra measure not to wherever it is admissible and does not remove valuable content, but the amount to which it happens is becoming increasingly concerning, for me at least.

Now on SO, I feel like it's not a big issue at the moment. We certainly have people who get offended at everything, but the silent consensus still seems to be "nobody cares" in general.

Comment: Not just the internet.

Comment: This post requires a *TRIGGER WARNING* for those offended by the incorrect use of "its".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm slightly offended by caps + italics at once...

Comment: @Patrice ***sOrRy***

Comment: Error A0A "Apostrophe Not Found"

Answer (score -6):

I would say that part of the problem with your question is that (at least in America) the drinking is seen as a requirement especially in advertising. This over pushing of the products causes people to get fed up with the push of it in general don't wan't to have to deal with it in places where it doesn't need to be. When talking about a developer survey the use of alcohol doesn't play into that in some people's opinion.

Comment: The drinking example was just an example... This doesn't really answer this question. Sure, I can understand why alcohol consumption might be considered irrelevant in the survey, but offensive? My first reaction would be: _"Come on! Get over it!"_

Comment: If _"You won't have fun unless you drink! "_ is seen as offensive, maybe we need to redefine that word.

Comment: @Cerbrus sure it is an example, but where do you draw the line about what someone should get over and what should actually be changed? One of the big problems in the software industry in general is diversity and that can be linked directly to behavior that is offensive to others. Just because you don't think something is offensive doesn't  mean that others might find it offensive. There is nothing wrong with someone posting their concerns about something so they can be considered and if found valid and properly handled. Just because someone posts a concern doesn't something needs done.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Maybe the definition of "Offensive" got twisted over the last few years to include even the slightest "bump"...

Comment: @Cerbrus Or maybe people realized that people have different levels for what they consider offensive based on circumstances and that it is not a simple black and white definition

Comment: @JoeW: Where we draw the line is hard to define. However, what I meant in the question was cases the average population would just shrug off as a small joke.

Comment: _"One of the big problems in the software industry in general is diversity and that can be linked directly to behavior that is offensive to others"_ - wow. [citation needed], for both claims.

Comment: @Cerbrus The problem is that people now seem to think that they have a RIGHT to NEVER be offended. I see it as highly immature. Life is offensive and hard, we have to live with that. Maybe because I have a very very very dark sense of humor it doesn't impact me, but I do see that trend in general as well where people are extremely careful of ANYTHING because it may offend one person. I understand that people have different threshold to offense.... but some people seem to be pushing it (like in your example)

Comment: @Patrice: 100% that.

Comment: @JoeW to me, the problem isn't that people realize (or don't) that we have different thresholds. My problem with this is that the human experience can be so vast people can find offense in ANYTHING (I lost my father to sickness 5 years ago and I had a super hard time getting over it... am I allowed to stop anyone mentioning the word "dad" because of this? NO. Should I? GOD NO. Is it normal I feel sad every time I see/read/hear dad or father? Yes. Should I make it a big deal? OF COURSE NOT). If my experience can make "dad" offensive (or hurtful), where do we stop? THAT'S the issue I think.

Comment: @Cerbrus There is plenty of evidence that there is a problem. http://www.latimes.com/business/la-fi-women-tech-20150222-story.html

Comment: @JoeW: Can we please not bring the "women in tech" debate into this? Thanks.

Comment: Personally, I don't get offended by anything on the internet to enough of an extent to care. I care about the Site quality of the community im in, and recognize wildly offensive stuff (to most) is inappropiate and harmful to it, but beyond that, I honestly could not possibly care less if people badmouth, insult, or otherwise rude talk me on the internet.

Comment: @Magisch *"I don't get offended so nobody else should either"*?

Comment: more like @jonrsharpe "people who waste their precious time of day getting angry at people on the internet are not very smart"

Comment: @Cerbrus We can't ignore the women in tech debate in this question since that issue boils down to the same issue that you are complaining about now.

Comment: @Magisch I agree it is good if you can ignore things that you find offensive but that is not something that everyone is willing to do. Personally the issue about alcohol doesn't bother me but I posted it as an example.

Comment: @JoeW the people who can't ignore it can flag and move on, or edit and move on. There is nothing that stands to be gained from annoying random people on the internet with what you do and don't find offensive.

Comment: @JoeW but where do you draw the line is the question. I understand and wholeheartedly TRY to not be offensive to anyone (my spoken language is WAY more colorful than what is seen here). But I mean, there are other more constructive things to do than argue about should I be offended or not. Just remove the offensive post (flag/edit), and move on. I don't think anything good can come out of a "what *should* be seen as offensive" discussion...

Comment: I don't care for offending anyone on purpose either, because its not my style and I don't feel the need to. But I don't think letting people know you are or incessant complaining in either way is going to achieve anything but laughther directed their way and disgust.

Comment: @Magisch you understand that the outcome you're describing is a lack of empathy on the part of others, rather than some failing of the person raising their head above the parapet to say *"that offends me"*, right? *"incessant complaining"* isn't what we're talking about.

Comment: Empathy, or the lack thereof, is a slippery slope. Soon we'll reach the point where the best way to demonstrate empathy with everyone ever is to stay completely silent. Good luck getting anything done with silence. (I regret any offence caused as a result of this comment.)

Comment: To make matters more complicated: Saying someone lacks the ability to empathize with someone that's offended for some reason, illustrates a certain lack of empathy with the person that thinks it's silly to be offended by that... Which could be considered offensive.