# Moderator removed my good-natured response to gender-exclusive language

Tags: discussion, gender

*This message was written to Stack Overflow support. I wanted to post it here in Meta to get the community's response as well. It's a little scatterbrained because I'm pretty tilted, but I wanted to write it up before I became too discouraged and swept my feelings under the mat.*

> Dear StackOverflow,
>
> I want to contribute on your website, but I experience gender-exclusive language on your site almost every day. I keep a positive attitude about it and still provide helpful answers, but I feel it's unfair to leave such language completely unrecognized. Moderators seem to be burying the issue, making it impossible for me to effect change amongst my peers. What should I do?
>
> Sincerely,
>   naomik

---

This question is not addressed by [Should I remove 'fluff' when editing questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions). I am asking what I can do to not feel so powerless when it comes to combating sexist language on SO.

I don't expect Stack Overflow to be a forum for societal issues, but as a female in a male-dominated industry, it can be very challenging facing gender-exclusive language and mindsets on a daily basis. I think I keep a pretty level head when I've encountered such language. I'll usually reply with some tongue-in-cheek remark to prompt others to think about the language they use when addressing their colleagues or the community on SO. Yeah, I get that it's off-topic, but it's so ingrained in user language that it often goes by completely undetected - both by the people writing with gender-exclusive language and people reading it. I write to support today to let you know that I'm officially offended - which is remarkably difficult to do. Not because someone used gender-exclusive language, but because a moderator buried it to make it look like nothing happened.

**Context:** The question started with: "I know this is going to be easy for you guys ..." - my answer started with "This would've been easier if I was a boy ..." via: [PHP Arrays: Grouping, Sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39459787/php-arrays-grouping-sum)

meagar removed the gender-exclusive language from the question and my playful remark in my answer. This effectively removes my voice as a user. I know SO is not my bulletin board for social justice, but I wasn't exactly picking fights with the OP over the matter. These aren't paragraphs of text or bickering arguments. This is natural language that people use when they're speaking to the public. I was only raising a pinkie finger of awareness. meagar's actions trivialize my efforts and bury a serious issue that I encounter very frequently. This isn't helping women that are challenged by this issue - in fact, the opposite is true: meagar's actions have harmed me. I am now isolated and the only party that feels the negative impact of the event. I kept a good attitude about the OP's language and still offered a very helpful reply. The single-sentence acknowledgement of the OP's language might be just enough to help other readers be aware of the issue without being disruptive to the content of the answer. But now I get to experience gender-exclusive language and be the only one to know it happened.

**Here's how I get to see it:** User solicits help of of male community. User receives help from 30k reputation female user. Female user nudges that non-males can answer too. SO moderators edit her answer to leave the 99% of the text that serves SO's purpose. Male user got what he came for. Female user discriminated against and silenced. All future visitors blind/ignorant to the abuse.

After my voice was taken away from me, I attempted to remove my answer. I no longer wanted to be part of a discussion where I wasn't allowed to have a voice. I didn't want to contribute my effort/knowledge to a question that would not take ownership for the way I was excluded. I do not want the community to benefit at my expense. That is not fair. meagar's response to me trying to remove my answer: he threatened to suspend my account.

What planet am I on? How the hell is this acceptable? At what point does SO acknowledge the issue and support users that struggle within the SO community? I've donated thousands of hours to helping people on SO - most of which were received by very graceful/grateful people - but what does SO do for me when I need help? Threaten to suspend me??

**Deleted comment thread for reference and context of exchange between meagar and me:**

[image: Screenshot of comment thread]

I don't even need SO to say they have my back or fight alongside me –  I'm willing to do it on my own, and tactfully too. What I cannot accept is being completely muted and sentenced to an eternal prison of gender-exclusive language.

Comment: Can't 'guys' be used to address both genders? I don't want to start a flame war, but isn't the word often used to describe a group or either gender? Also, meager removed both instances, in the question and the answer to remove the issue altogether

Comment: Would you address a room full of women as "guys" ? It doesn't offend me – it can't, even – if I took offence to such talk, I'd be offended all day long. You'll have to ask yourself what's right in any particular scenario. My whole point is to challenge people to think about how they speak and whether or not their language excludes women (or others).

Comment: @naomik: So that's why meta has felt so dry lately... we just didn't have enough of these discussions! I feel reinvigorated already!

Comment: @naomik *"Would you address a room full of women as "guys""* i know some women who do

Comment: *"I attempted to remove my answer"* to correct you according to the [edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39459833/revisions) you didn't try to remove it but rather vandalized it

Comment: @Memor-X I was not allowed to delete an accepted answer and I would not consider it vandalism.

Comment: @naomik No of course not, but as a site that has both genders, it's appropriate to address audience as 'guys' as it's addressing all *potential* answerers as a group consisting of both genders

Comment: Another female here. I would have edited question and answer too to remove the salutation parts, not because of gender issues, but because of them being irrelevant to the problem. This has nothing to do with discrimination.

Comment: Hahaha "guys" - the slang plural of man - "address all **potential** answerers" - So I'm no longer a potential candidate for answering a question? *sigh*

Comment: @naomik Deleting text in your answer and replacing with text irrelevant to the question or text that invalidates it as an answer is something I would consider vandalism

Comment: @BoltClock I'm having some difficulty measuring the sincerity of your comment :s

Comment: @naomik Would you address a group of men and women as girls or guys? By potential answerers I mean the whole audience or group that will view and potentially answer it. In this sense, guys means a group consisting of either gender. Aside from that, gender is completely irrelevant on a site where the primary goal is to provide an archive of knowledge to future readers

Comment: @naomik: Just for the lols ;)

Comment: -4 votes already for even posting this – it appears even my concerns aren't worth talking about. RIP SO

Comment: @naomik as said by Glorfindel vandalizing your answer like that is frowned upon. being unable to delete it because it's accepted isn't a valid reason to do so

Comment: I didn't vote; however, votes in this case may be taken as agreement or disagreement with the premise of your post. I personally don't think that gender has anything to do with anything on Stack Overflow, and references to gender should be edited out of posts with prejudice.

Comment: @JonClements thank you. I couldn't access them.

Comment: @Memor-X thanks, I missed that the answer was accepted.

Comment: @naomik The easiest way may be not to disclose your gender in 1st place (you don't need to do so). I appreciate any women at the site, since they are rare in our business, and mostly give good and fresh innovative views and inputs on any stuff. Don't let the guys scare you away. Your gender may be irrelevant for your question's content.

Comment: The "vandalism" of the answer doesn't alter the fact that I've still been given no advice on how to affect change amongst my peers

Comment: πάντα ῥεῖ oh so kind of like Mulan then? Do I get to do a big "surprise, I'm actually a girl" at some point? Or do I just eternally parade around with the boys calling everyone dude and bro?

Comment: @naomik I understand your frustration and your struggle, but gender isn't a quantifiable thing on Stack Overflow. If this were a forum of the olden days, you might be able to change something, but here your struggle is just... off-topic.

Comment: @JonClements must I be censored in meta.se too? I can't even reply to your comment because you deleted my post too quickly.

Comment: @naomik you seem very quick to jump to the word *censorship* when there isn't any... You posted a non-answer that I've really no idea what message you were trying to convey (and certainly doesn't help/either degrades the point you're trying to make) so it got deleted - it's really that simple.

Comment: @JonClements I like how the issue is so simple for you. I took everyone's input into account and the understanding I have is that "guys" addresses either gender – so that includes me now – and if I want to participate on the site, I just have to go along with that because raising >0 words about the issue is off-topic...

Comment: ... So the answer is to "Be a man" which comes as a delight because it's a song from one of my favourite Disney movies, Mulan. If you have a different "answer" for my question, feel free to provide it. Otherwise can I have the answer that solved my problem undeleted/uncensored/unsilenced? Pick whichever word you like.

Comment: @naomik _Mulan_ is too flat for the topic. You could have mentioned _pocahontas_ the same way. There's more depth, c'mon girl. BTW my daughter's name is noémi same like yours. You know what the meaning is? The answer is be a peer, and being a peer is actually easy for women, if they once got it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I believe Mulan is a perfect analogue. They're expecting men, so if I look like one and act like one, they won't have to know the feelings I'm holding inside. My misery will be my own and I won't have to burden anyone else with it.

Comment: Never before have I felt so abandoned. Read this thread. Look at every up-vote and back-pat. The community has spoken, unanimously, against me. When I chose an answer that reflects the voice of others here, it was also deleted. My concerns now have -9 votes. I am bound to indefinitely suffer ignorant, gender exclusive language on one of my favourite websites. I am completely disarmed from combatting it in any meaningful way. And everyone here has no problem with that.

Comment: @naomik Be a women please. You have much more power than men in any direction. Seems you just didn't discover that yet. You have the power to give new life into the real world, just to start with. Don't let men diminish you, kick their cojones and they'll cry like babies. Be self aware and confident. I dunno what to say more, that's what I'm at least trying to teach my daughter.

Comment: To me, it looks like you are trying to tell people "I'm a girl" and there is nothing wrong with being a girl, but your gender doesn't matter here on SO, be you boy or girl. The removal of your text had nothing to do with your gender but simply it was unnecessary text, you're the one making it into a gender issue.

Comment: @naomik at the end of Mulan didn't the emperor name Mulan as the ***hero*** of china rather than ***heroine*** or china? also askers aren't seeking *your* help, they are seeking the help of the ***entire Stack Overflow Community***. askers have no way of knowing if a potential answerer is male, female, Hideyoshi (Baka and Test) or Abyssal Futanari (how Northern-hime is born in an all female army), especially before said answerer even posts

Comment: @Memor-X and the entire Stack Overflow community is summarized as "guys", ok. Look, I don't give a f*** about people getting my gender wrong. I'm actually concerned about how it affects others. I just don't believe burying the events actually *solves* the issue. It only a band-aid. No awareness generated.

Comment: @Epodax haha yep. yeah all that other stuff I said in my post was just fluff. I really just meant to say "Dear StackOverflow, I'm a girl. Recognize."

Comment: I'm sorry if I come of as rude, english isn't my native language and it isn't always easy to explain what I mean without coming off as rude, but I'll try none the less: You state in your question that you are aware that it's considered off-topic, and yet you are surprised that it's removed? It has nothing to do with gender, it has nothing to do with "silencing you", it was removed because it was off-topic and didn't belong here on SO, had I written / done the same as you, just reversed it with male part instead of girl, then it would STILL have been removed.

Comment: For reference, the English language has gender neutral uses for the word "guys" which seems to be applicable here. See: [What is a feminine version of 'guys'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19074/what-is-a-feminine-version-of-guys) and [Is "guy" gender-neutral?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11816/is-guy-gender-neutral)

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara don't get hung up on the specific instance that triggered this post. I get called "man" and "sir" on the site all the time. Again, not really offended; I handle it well. I can imagine it's very detrimental to other users tho.

Comment: This is going to be a pointless post on Meta, why? Because you don't seem intend on a debate or soloution other than "I'm right!", because everyone who doesn't seem to agree with you are just "sheep following the herd", and possibly couldn't just be disagreeing with you on their own merits? You seem to be nursing the idea that it's you VS Stack Overflow. Also, please don't pretend to say that you're not offended and that you are, "speaking for others", let people speak for themselves.

Comment: @naomik: not much time to respond at present, but just to let you know that I (for one at least) am sympathetic to the issue of gender on SO (and have posted here on Meta several times about it). However, I am minded to agree with others that adding off-topic remarks to posts is not the solution. Perhaps there are some other ways in which this theme can be tackled? I will see if I can make some suggestions.

Comment: @halfer I believe that many would in fact support and do their best to help solve such a issue should there be one (I don't know whether there is or not so I'm not gonna comment on that part), but the issue I'm having with this post and comments is the way the topic is approached, claiming that you are being "silenced" because off-topic chatter was removed from your question / answer and then taking on the whole "Everyone is sheep and I'm all alone"  - is NOT the way to solve issues, a mature and civil discussion is.

Comment: I sympathize with the fundamental issue at hand - it's easy to say "we don't care about gender" when you're not addressed as "she" and with "all right, girls!", etc. all the time. I agree that the off-topic content was rightly removed from the question, though - it's what we do to *everyone*. To call this some sort of sexist discrimination is highly unreasonable, especially for a five-year veteran of the site who *must* know this happens all the time.

Comment: @Pekka웃 in the context of this question, there's probably a better way you can address other users than "idiotic".  Given that the issue stems from misunderstanding what is appropriate to edit out, I felt the 'should fluff be removed" dupe was applicable.  We'd close questions with it if they were asked in similar ways about "why did my thanks get removed, I don't like that", or "why did my life story get removed, I don't like that".

Comment: @davidism OK, "idiotic" was not the right word choice. It's still not a good closing, IMO. The focus is clearly something else here.

Comment: And I wish there would be only one gender (actually, I don't) so we would not have to deal with stupidities like this. As a female I am sick and tired of other females overreacting to completely benign stuff. Get over it. If you feel the need to go around and yell "I am a girl" then first it is you the one with gender issues, and second don't be surprised if you stir up responses of any kind.

Comment: @Pekka웃 want to discuss about the opposite situation? I routinely get associated to being afemale because of my name. I normally laugh it up and see it as a sign that people don't necessarily think IT = man. In any case, you don't grabasoap box and become a social justice warrior... At least not on Stack

Comment: @Patrice My sincere apologies, I also though you are the girl :)

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar the woes of having a French name :p. No need to apologize, i prefer people thing of my contributions than what is (or isn't) between my legs

Comment: @Patrice I know many Italian guys with same problem - if it is a problem :) Anyway, I fully agree with you, I never judge people through gender glasses. Also, plenty of people I know thought I was a Indian guy, based on my name - it took us few years to figure that out and then we had good laughs :P

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar i lost count how many customers i've only discussed via email get in the office expecting a woman, then get extremely surprised by being greeted by someone who looks closer to Hagrid from Harry Potter

Comment: @Patrice `I routinely get associated to being afemale because of my name.` me, too - but then the gravatar fixes that quickly on SO. Not so much in correspondence. A woman's situation is arguably still different because there's no misunderstanding to clean up. `In any case, you don't grabasoap box and become a social justice warrior... At least not on Stack` no, but it's fair to discuss options how to correct people who address you the wrong way and not fall afoul of SO's rules in the process (which is where this discussion should ideally have headed)

Comment: @Pekka웃 Ideally I'd suggest creating a new question, as I believe that in order to properly address any issues there might be, would alter the current question too much and would by that right be a "new" question :)

Comment: @Pekka웃 and had that been the tone of the discussion i would love to try and chime in constructively. But this post is just one more rant to look at. I'd genuinely be all for a question discussing these options.

Comment: @JonClements In my opinion, "Be a man" is a perfectly valid response/answer to the question *what should I do*? Snarky? Yes. But it's for her to decide how she expresses her ideas - whether it helps her case or not.

Comment: @ayhan [It is never a good answer](http://www.medicaldaily.com/what-it-means-be-man-how-male-gender-stereotypes-try-fit-growing-boys-mold-and-fail-326450)

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't take issue with the "Marry me?" remark. That's the bit that raises my eyebrow.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I didn't have the comments to link as proof at that time. I could only make my "case" with what I had. To clarify, it doesn't offend me tho. It just makes me sad that people find it perfectly acceptable to engage strangers like that. Literally engage in this case, lol.

Comment: Males know that your name is of female. They address you as male to make you chat for a while. _Nobody calls me "Man" or "guy" because they know that I am_. You got the hit?

Comment: @Mr_Green `They address you as male to make you chat for a while` `You got the hit?` uh... what?

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A site. You repeatedly claim that you understand this ("I don't expect Stack Overflow to be a forum for societal issues," "I know SO is not my bulletin board for social justice"), but it's obvious that you don't. If you want to be snippy with people who are just using the vernacular term for addressing an audience or group ("y'all" would be a nice alternative, but it's very uncommon outside of Texas), please take it to a site like Wordpress or Tumblr.

Comment: @Pekka웃 they try to hit her. (_not literally_)

Comment: @Mr_Green you mean hit *on* her. The distinction is important. Calling a woman "him" seems like a rather weird way to attract their attention though (apart from the fact that hitting on women *or* guys isn't really desired behaviour on Stack Overflow.)

Comment: "Hey girl I like the way you do dependency injections, wanna grab dinner?"

Comment: @Pekka웃 not everyone but many does that. Some people look for lines to what to chat. and then they get this stupid idea to call her as man. By this you will confirm that she is "she", as you assumed and right now you are chatting with her. btw, nice pickup line :) and yes I meant `hit on her`.

Comment: @naomik FWIW I got very upset shortly after writing my answer and posted this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284569/set-a-benchmark-on-acceptable-behaviour I do believe that sometimes the pressures that some women feel being in such a male dominated field need to be acknowledged.

Comment: @Yvette I agree that the pressures should be acknowledged. The story you share in your post is disheartening to read about. But in a place where majority rules, what can we really do? **Just flag it and live with it**, is what they're all telling us. Comments get removed and at some point in the distant future, repeat offenders or punished – or something. Win? heh

Comment: @Yvette to this end, I'm pretty surprised at your response to my other question about graying/fading out of answers. It's all about equal voice which could be a contributor to having women's voices heard on this site. Your response indicated you saw absolutely no value in it (you answered with sarcasm), which was a bit shocking considering some of the other things I see you fighting for. *shrugs*

Comment: @Yvette anyway, I appreciate your feedback on this question. I'm mostly burnt out on it. There's so much hate and my words have been misconstrued more times than I have the remaining energy to respond to appropriately. I have these little flag thingies tho. Like some sort of bulletproof vest, I think? I wasn't guaranteed they will have an impact on anything I care about, but it's also not my place to care about inequality here anymore. We're here for programming-related stuff only and everything always goes according to plan!

Comment: @naomik ttytt I didn't link you as the author to the other question and my answer was really just a joke. I don't usually answer like that. when I realised you were the author, I was annoyed at myself. As I can see where you're at and that answer is not the right thing. I am deleting that answer, as it has no value and it really it a joke.. the animated gif. I half expected it to be deleted. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Yvette: Why does it matter who asked the question? What makes that answer acceptable on anyone else's question, when it makes you annoyed when you realize naomik asked it?

Comment: @Cerbrus because she is burnt out and upset and it's OK to be mindful of individuals. The world doesn't have to be dog eat dog, we are to care, even for a total stranger.

Comment: @Yvette: So that does make it okay to post this answer on _any other user's_ question, even though that user might be even worse for wear? (we don't know) I'm not saying I dislike the answer. However, I'm not fond of this double standard.

Comment: @Yvette no need to be sorry. I only called attention out to it because it's painfully evident how sarcastic remarks diminish the potential for a constructive conversation to take place on sensitive topics. I've already eaten my humble pie, but I'm sure someone will still point out the irony/hypocrisy of me saying that.

Comment: @meagar, to some capacity, I'm developing an appreciation for the rules of off-topic content. I come from the era of IRC where constructive conversation was constantly derailed by petty nitpickers and specious cynics. This having been my first encounter with MSO, I did not know how quickly a question could degrade to illogical, combative word-twisting and cyclical back-patting; taking me right back to those days of IRC. People can "follow the rules" and still get away with murder – this is a serious problem, in my opinion.

Comment: ... While some users demonstrated a profound undesrtanding of the more subtle and delicate parts of the issue I raised, it doesn't surprise me that the pack of dogs quickly neutralized any potential impact they had. So, while I feel it has been mostly useless to voice unpopular opinion, I thank the moderator team for remaining tactful and constructive. ...

Comment: ... However, I am unlikely to raise further issues on MSO because of this extremely pugnacious tendency within the MSO community; and I'm sure that will make a lot users in this thread very happy. Everyone seems to have an opinion, but so very few retain the effort required to generate useful and logically sound input. ...

Comment: ... Honestly, this makes me wish for a platform where it was possible to have your content deleted if you failed to demonstrate logical reasoning. The harm of allowing *incorrect* content prevail in any form is toxic to the very community a platform wishes to support. I don't mean to imply I am without logical flaw; but such a platform would enable/encourage contributors to learn from their mistakes. Hypothesis: maybe such a platform doesn't exist because so few people would be willing to set their pride aside to learn how to be a better contributor.

Comment: @naomik I totally understand and am discussing this issue with the community team. I'm taking a short break. But this needs to be dealt with. People mistake compassion and treating people as individuals with a double standard. Everyone is different and had you been a man making a similar fight feeling burnt out and made that comment to me, I would've deleted that answer. These people fail to comprehend that life can be about making allowances and trying to understand and help people, instead of piling on outrage and pressuring people to a point they don't want to be in the community.

Comment: @naomik don't give up. Take a break like I am. We need to be strong and not fold under the pressure. The majority  does not apply this pile on behaviour, nor condone disrespect. I have called you out on where you made mistakes in handling that question, and you handled that gracefully, in the face of much opposition and some shaming. There are many people who are unable to be introspective and learn from their mistakes. They are the ones we are having difficulty with, as is the entire community. It's this LOUD minority that screams unfair whenever any issues of gender are raised.

Comment: ... They sit like a pack of watch dogs ready to argue every little thing, rather than to understand the true meaning of what is being said. This type of derailment is at best not useful, at worst most destructive to the community.

Comment: @Yvette - It's good to take a step back. Consider that most women wish to be treated equally. To the point where it's often a good thing to use gender neutral pronouns not to offend anyone. Naomi takes offense at the word "Guy" which, at least in the US (confirmed by dictionaries) is used as non-gender. SE answers are expected to be just that and nothing but. Mods are volunteers, who try to keep things flowing. Killing spam, reminding members to [be nice](http://money.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice), etc.

Comment: I subscribe to Nassim Taleb's  mantra "If you see fraud and do not say "fraud", you are a fraud." In this case, substitute 'misogynist' for 'fraud.' IRL, I heard a man refer to a woman I knew as a "blonde bimbo". I didn't know him, but I knew the woman. "Are you taking about her? (I pointed). She has a PhD in bimolecular engineering, and is smarter than both of us combined." (and I talked to my wife about how it must be awful to have some stereotype about your natural hair color)

Comment: And if anyone is unkind on my Money.SE (i am a mod) I'd kill such a comment, and email them with a suspension. To be clear, SE has no place for "unkind", but it also wont allow every stack to be a soapbox for an off-topic issue. Again, the distinction is IRL, talk it out, on SE, edit it all out, keep it on topic.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Nice words.

Comment: Related: *[Perl: The Next Generation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TAOxGjNbp_Y)* (not really specific at all to Perl, but actually about some kind of communities). 39 min 31 secs.

Comment: Your [original answer](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/39459833/1) shows you giving an answer but providing an extremely irrelevant statement "this would've been easier if I was a boy" What the hell? What does that have to do with ANYTHING? Code has no gender, you're typing characters and compiling it. The fact that you can't wrap your head around the fact that guys in this case isn't referring to boys is the root of the whole problem. Why did you stare at that part of his question so much instead of worrying about the actual question at hand?

Comment: @naomik what makes you say that? See [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67148/can-i-use-you-guys-when-it-includes-gals-northeast-usa), this was what the original question intended to use "guys" as.

Comment: @interwebz you don't get it. It's about unconscious gender exclusion. we (girls) have come to accept/expect that men (and even some women) will refer to us as "guys" despite the fact that is a term for a group of men. does this unconscious discrimination affect women (or men)? If so, how? if you need a programming analogy, you're getting hung up on an instance when i'm talking about a class.

Comment: @naomik suppose I (male) am talking to a group of 2 boys and 2 girls. I say "you guys want pizza tonight?" Is that this unconscious discrimination that you mentioned?

Comment: @interwebz of course. what impact do you think it has subconsciously on all parties? men hear themselves addressed as their identifier, but women don't. maybe women are less likely to speak up because they subconsciously didn't feel included in the question. the point is, i don't know, you don't know, and the people involved in this hypothetical scenario don't know because it's *subconscious*. is there a way we can become conscious of its effects tho? even partially? does it seem unfair (ie *imbalanced*) to just pick one over the other? what are the consequences of leaving it unaddressed?

Comment: @naomik but wasn't guys defined as another possible gender neutral term? It is at least if use in the 2nd person, but obviously not in the 3rd person or in plural. Are women offended by being called a gender neutral term? Different women are different. see [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11816/is-guy-gender-neutral)

Comment: @interwebz you're hung up on the instance again. The bigger picture is there is gender discrimination in more places than you are conscious of and (I believe) there are severe consequences because of this.

Comment: @naomik so in this case, was the gender discrimination intended? I don't think the user was *trying* to offend people, but i feel like your original starting comment in your answer took offense to the user's words.

Comment: You are a very wierd woman if I check the edit history. He deleted one line; 'This would've been easier if I was a boy'. Next thing you do, is writing all kind of wierd stuff into the awnser ... 'User's voice abused by moderators?' Only one word came into my mind when i read that. 'Dafuq??'...

Comment: How could you see any deleted comments here?

Comment: When considering a post, you really should read it from the OP's perspective, if there is any.

Comment: @InsurgentPointerException that was so insightful, thanks!

Answer (score 141):

I haven't seen a moderator's response on this post yet, so thought I should add my own.

We accept and welcome contribution from anyone, anywhere, anytime. You won't find anyone who would vote to close, delete, downvote or refuse to accept any of your posts because you are female, and if you do, please tell us.

However, you must understand that from an objective point of view, no one cares. The visitor from Google coming to read a question and its answer doesn't care that you're male, female or anything in between. They don't care about your pronouns or gender identity. They care about the question and the answers.

Thus, it's the job of us moderators (as well as members of the community who voluntarily give up some of their time for the sake of the site), to remove noise. Noise being bad answers (which are voted down and/or edited), bad questions (which are voted down and/or closed and/or edited) and irrelevant comments (which are flagged and deleted).

The action the moderator took against the comments on the post were to remove noise, and not to censor (as evidence, a moderator included a screenshot of all the deleted comments as they were, if we wanted to ignore, censor and pretend that things never happened, he wouldn't have done it, and I wouldn't be responding here).

---

As for the issue of gender exclusive language. This is the internet. People will talk and say things in whatever way they want, and educating them on these matters is not our goal. You have editing privileges, if you want to make a change, edit the question so that the language is more neutral. Answering with a passive-aggressive tone so that the asker feels embarrassed about their contribution to the site is *not* OK.

Comment: So much this. SO is about a community of information. When I answer user123345489's question not once does gender go through my head.

Comment: The moral of the story is: OP should have checked their [priviliges](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) before ranting, because they would have noticed they can edit posts.

Answer (score 105):

As a female in a male dominated industry, let me give you my thoughts on the matter:

Meagar did the right thing.

That comment was just that: A comment. It provided no extra benefit to your answer, and was correctly removed. As a user with full editing privileges, you could have handled this differently from the start. You could have edited the line that bothered you out of the question, and left an edit summary explaining why you did it, rather than putting a comment in your answer's text. Maybe left a comment explaining why you did it, if you wanted to be sure the OP saw it. But adding irrelevant noise to your answer is not the way to handle this.

You may look at my low rep and account with a couple years to its name and think I just don't understand, I don't see this issue because I'm not active enough on the main site. Well, I'm not going to argue about not seeing this, but I peruse the main site a lot, even if I have no questions to ask and no answers to give. But what I *do* see is a lot of meta posts. I am very active on Meta, as a brief glance of my Meta profile will tell you. In my opinion, if something truly heated is going to come up, it's going to be on Meta in some form. Whether it starts here or migrates here, a lot of issues do end up coming here in some form.

There have been other posts on the gender issue. I've answered at least one of them, I've commented on a lot of the ones I saw, and my stance remains the same: Stack Overflow is *not* the place to handle these issues or try to educate users about these issues. Stack Overflow is for *programming* problems, not gender inequality issues and lessons.

Now don't get me wrong- If you see something outrageous in terms of someone being sexist, *flag it immediately.* The mods will handle it and clean it up. But someone using "guys" to refer to the collective users of Stack Overflow is nothing to really waste your time with. As others have addressed, "guys" is a term generally used to mean a group of people of any gender. While it may not have originally meant that, it generally does now.

If you see someone clean up noise that adds nothing to your question or answer, I urge you to take a step back before you get annoyed and think, "Does this really add anything to my post? Does it address the problem at hand?" If the answer to those questions is no, whatever was removed really doesn't need to be there.

We're writing posts for the future users with the same issues, or trying to. Don't we want them to see cleaned up and high quality contributions, not tongue-in-cheek remarks to comments that really hurt nothing?

Comment: Thank you +1. I must say it's sad that the _"As a female..."_ line is necessary, in this discussion. It's like "us guys" just aren't taken seriously (or even are ignored) when we answer discussions like this.

Comment: @Cerbrus Psst, I think in this case it's to point out that Kendra knows what the author is talking about.

Comment: @Seth It's a little of both, really. Partially to point out that I'm in a similar position, and partially because in other (not necessarily here) discussions on the matter, I've found the person with the issue more willing to listen if they realized I was female. When someone's annoyed or feeling on their own, it's reassuring to know they have someone similar in the same position to speak with, and also easier to listen to someone who's been there before or may have been there before.

Comment: To give a quick list of a couple of the other gender discussions I mentioned, for those interested that hadn't seen them: [Diminishing Numbers of Women in Programming and the SO Experience](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309908), which spawned [Merge request, after seeing how the the other half experiences SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/298440), and [Does the SO community view itself as gender neutral?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281295/2607247). Those were just a couple that I found easy to get to. There are a number more.

Comment: Interesting to read the linked posts. I graduated BSEE in 1984 and the women were 8% of the graduating class. I'm both surprised and sorry to see the current numbers aren't dramatically higher. I work in a high school, and it seems to me the STEM issue needs to be addressed at a much younger level. I hope my grandkids aren't going to make the same observation and wonder why this hasn't shifted over the decades.

Answer (score 71):

Contrarily to how you might *feel* about these moderator actions, this has *nothing* to do with gender. We welcome contributions of everyone; every gender, race or sexual orientation alike. The goal of Stack Overflow is to build a Q&A site with questions and answers of the highest quality, *especially* aimed at future visitors with the question who arrive here via search engines. That means that elements in posts which would be perfectly normal (even part of standard politeness) in, say, an e-mail conversation or a discussion forum, can be deleted here because they draw away attention from the real problem. For reference, see [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/295232) on Meta.

If the question had started with just

> I know this is going to be easy for a lot of you, but ...

it would have been removed as well. Removing this part of the question means your opening sentence

> This would've been easier if I was a boy

doesn't make sense anymore, so it had to be deleted as well.

> I attempted to remove my answer

Given the circumstances, it wouldn't have led to any trouble at all if you did. Granted, that wasn't possible because the answer was accepted ... Instead you [vandalized](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39459833/revisions#spacer-eebf1f74-0706-4297-b684-b1e24f4021c8) your own post, and that's something that's frowned upon.

Comment: I understand the reasoning behind the decision. Now help me understand how I can be a part of your community.

Comment: IMHO, the best way to contribute is writing questions and answers of high quality. A quality where you can recognize the post is from an experienced user, even if the block with your name and 30k reputation is nowhere to be seen.

Comment: Ok so the advice I'm getting is "ignore the fact many of your peers address you by the wrong gender. just provide them with good answers." ...

Comment: @naomik I usually try to determine the gender by looking at their username and profile (but this can be misleading; some users use model pictures instead of their own). If in doubt, I'll use "he/she" or "they". I realize not everyone works that way. I'm never in the same situation as you, but I'd just mention something like this in a comment directed at them (and delete it if is resolved). In this particular question, you can just edit out the fluff.

Comment: Your profile picture anecdote is delightful. Thank you for sharing it. I used to use [my face](https://github.com/naomik) as a profile picture too until I received too much harassment from other users. Then I changed it to a laughing hyena face (which can still be seen on [my twitter profile](https://twitter.com/naomikyoto)). After I got sick of that, I changed it to a nice beetle. Beetles are very interesting creatures. You can't tell, but the one in my picture is a guy/bro beetle. For purposes of fitting in.

Comment: @naomik to be clear we (SO moderators) take harassment very seriously when it is brought to our attention. I'm all for fixing pointless use of gendered pronouns and challenging assumptions that might well be wrong, but not at the expense of reducing the quality of the questions/answers.

Comment: I usually do the same thing as Glorfindel when figuring out how to adress someone, as I'm sure most people do. Maybe its just that I'm a guy but it would never occur to me to take offense if someone used the wrong pronoun to adress me, since its so inconsequential.

Comment: When I suggest edits, asides from fixups to formatting, grammar, spelling and punctuation - I will always remove anything irrelevant, I don't care about the gender - I only care about the quality of the post.

Answer (score 56):

There is a lot of general discussion about the broader issues but I haven't seen this specific question explicitly addressed yet:

> I am asking what I can do to not feel so powerless when it comes to combating sexist language on SO.

Quite a lot, actually. Anytime you see objectionable content, any or all of the following would be a great way to address the problem *and* help clean up:

- Edit the post to remove the offending content or render it inoffensive
- Leave an educational comment, written in a constructive **non-sarcastic** tone, advising the poster of what they did wrong and why they shouldn't continue to do so. Do not engage if they respond with their own sarcasm, snark, or insults. Instead, escalate for a moderator, who (at least speaking for myself) will *suspend the absolute shite* out of anybody they find leveling gender-based insults at other users.
- Flag the post for a moderator, explaining what is wrong, and know that the moderation team *absolutely has your back*. We take abusive behavior very seriously.
- In more egregious cases post on meta and bring it to the attention of the wider community, keeping in mind the goal is to raise awareness of the problem, not to start a witch hunt

The goal of Stack Overflow's Q&A format is and always has been on-topic content, with a high signal-to-noise ratio. Cluttering up the main site with off-topic "meta" discussion about the site's content is not the answer, regardless of how important you think the discussion is to have. The main site is simply *not* the forum for this.

---

On a personal note, I'm sorry that things played out so negatively for you, but at almost *six years* of SO participation, you should know that your content is up for editing by anybody who has earned the reputation required to do so, and that off-topic noise routinely gets removed from questions and answers. This is not censorship, this is not done to undermine your efforts or silence your voice or bury the issue, this is simply keeping the site's content *on-topic*.

I don't consider myself a sexist or a misogynist, quite the opposite. I edited the offending content out of the question because it was *noise*, and I edited your response out of your answer and deleted the ensuing comment thread because it was *noise*. I've edited almost 9000 posts and deleted 16,000 comments since becoming a moderator, for the same reason: To keep the content on-topic. There was no other motive at play on my end.

Comment: FWIW I don't regard you as doing anything wrong. I think the OP is feeling victimised in a situation where you were acting appropriately. The issue is the OP is feeling victimised from a more pervasive societal condition.

Comment: "Leave an educational comment, written in a constructive non-sarcastic tone," Notably, timgavin didn't seem to be the least bit offended by @naomik's *tone*. Up until the point where you decided to wield your mod privileges to edit a tiny, casual exchange that ran alongside a valid Q/A, **there was no issue**. The use of mod privileges here *caused* the issue.

Comment: @sequoiamcdowell Your comment is based on the false premise that, until I acted, there was no issue. The off-topic content was *itself* an issue that I was obligated to address. The issue being discussed here is not the degree of offense given or taken by the recipient of naomik's comments and answers. The content was not removed because it was offensive, if was removed because it was off-topic, timgavin's reaction to it has never been an important part of this thread.

Answer (score 53):

> User solicits help of of **male** community.

Here is where you started to go wrong

> **Male** user got what he came for.

Here is where it continued...

I have never once got the impression that I am taking part in a single-gender community, nor am I naive enough to believe that every person asking for help is also of a single gender.

If you remove the gender from both of these quotes then you come to the right conclusion - User A comes for help and sometime gets help. **IT'S THAT SIMPLE**.

I couldn't care less if the users post I am reading from is even human or not; if it helps me, I'm going to upvote it. If it's trash, it's getting downvoted.

Answer (score 37):

You were correct to call out the language. You (and everyone else) need to call it out because if you don't, it's going to take decades more than it's already going to take in order for it to stop. This is something my daughters are going to need to contend with ***probably until they retire*** *despite any effort that I spend now, while they're still in elementary school* and that makes me pretty sad.

But the way that you did it, despite being rather witty (I laughed as I read your narrative of what you wrote), added something very awkward to your answer especially once the language had been edited out of the question. It came off more antagonistic than tongue-in-cheek (again, especially in the absence of the language in the question).

The way to do it is to just ***edit it out***, and leave a summary similar to:

> I'm a woman that can answer this quite well, but felt reticent to post because of the wording that you used. I'm assuming good-faith so I just made a small edit, but please remember that we come in all shapes, sizes and genders. It's off-putting when you feel like you've been excluded.

We don't just talk about our diversity stats on a blog, we actually *care* about this a great deal. We hold regular forums within the company to find out places where people don't feel safe or included, and we work together to hold ourselves accountable for it and to fix it. This mindset doesn't just extend within the company, we also bring it to the way that we steer and lead our communities, and how we work with and teach the folks that so graciously donate their time as moderators. Problems don't get fixed unless you actively peel away the breadth until you can't find any more.

Meagar took the correct steps, but he doesn't have tools that let him make those sorts of edits and send a message to folks involved in an atomic way. He has to first make two edits, clean up a bunch of comments, and then react as people notice what he's done and .. it's not an easy job.

I'm glad you brought it here because it is a discussion worth having, and what you're doing *isn't* wrong, it just wasn't the best way to do it. I really hope that you continue helping by giving answers (frankly, [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) could use all the help it can get).

Comment: Is it a problem? Yes. Is this (vandalizing, calling it censorship and claiming modabuse) the solution? No.

Comment: @ArdaÖzkal I'm quite certain that I've communicated that in my answer; if you have any suggestions on how I could make that clearer, I'm completely open to hearing them :)

Comment: As usual Tim you do not fail to disappoint me. A great answer. As a woman pushing for this awareness, I've discovered it can be a tricky road trying to express issues without coming across as blaming or anti-male. It's something more pervasive and inbuilt within society and there are differences between the sexes, It's just knowing where these differences matter. (i.e. childbirth)

Comment: @Yvette Thank you :) I think you meant _not_ disappoint, then? I'm having a little trouble parsing the first sentence </awkward>

Comment: @TimPost I took a break from everything and slept and read the answer again. I'm sorry for saying that you didn't talk about stuff, you did, but i think that pointing out the issues before recommending what to do ("DON'T: Make more noise. DO: Edit it out.") could make the question clearer.

Comment: The problem with this answer is as follows: @naomik highlighted the gender misstep in a light-hearted way that turned out to be received quite well & left no hard feelings (i.e. she read the situation successfully). The approach you're suggesting here Tim is *much* more confrontational, verbose, less casual, and more likely to leave the asker feeling defensive (IMO). 'You didn't respond to sexism appropriately, please consult *Tim & Matt's Guide for Women: How to Respond to Sexism*' You don't see your response here as alienating?

Answer (score 28):

*Before I get started I'd like to point out that this isn't the first time someone has brought up this topic, and it will definitely not be the last time that we see it, be it here or on Meta.SE. Most people on Meta.SO already have a "set" stance regarding this topic; that's why the reaction could seem to be quite .. overdrawn.*

---

Let me start of by thanking you for posting this question. Hopefully this question and the discussion that it started will help the Stack Overflow community to finally let gender as a separating factor behind and move on. Posting this question and hosting this discussion was also pretty brave of you (the backlash was pretty much to be expected).

Now, what is Stack Overflow exactly / what is Stack Overflow supposed to be? The answer is quite simple, a neutral Q&A-site, driven and partly moderated by the community. The truth is, **most people here don't care about gender**, or anything at all apart from participating in this site. I do not care about it either. If a female or male answers my question, it doesn't make a difference to me, I'll be grateful either way.

Same goes for noise. Everything that has no impact on the Q&A at hand will be considered as noise and **will be removed**. It doesn't make a difference if you're saying "Hello", "Thanks", make a snarky remark or anything at all, if it doesn't improve/impact the Q/A it will be terminated **regardless of how oppressed the author may or may not feel.**

---

Let's get to the current issue. I'll try to break it down as to how I see it, and then try to explain exactly why what happened and what the reasoning behind it is, and what you **could have and probably should have** done differently.

**Step 1:** Someone posts a question, and uses "I know this is going to be easy for you guys" in there.

**Step 2:** You post an answer, and add a snarky remark ("This would've been easier if I was a boy") in response to his introduction.

**Step 3:** A moderator removes the introduction alongside your snarky remark.

**Step 4:** You chose to vandalize your own (pretty neat) answer.

**Step 5:** A moderator reversed the actions you took.

In step 1 & step 2 both of you, the author and you, added unnecessary noise to your text. Anyone is free to edit it out at sight; that's not new, that's how it's always been (at least as far as I can recall). In this case it happened to be Meagar, that's all. Anyone above 2k reputation could've done the same (and most people would have done the same).

What could you have done differently? Well, you could have gone the conflict-free route and simple edited the introduction out. It would have been totally fine (you removed noise), and you could've just posted an answer and moved on with your life. You didn't, and that's why we're here.

You should most definitely not have tried to vandalize your own answer though. That's not something anyone on this site appreciates, and that's nothing that'll get you a lot of sympathy or understanding either.

Also, please, watch out with "my voice was taken from me". The (elected) StackOverflow/Stack Exchange-moderators have *every right to do what Meagar did.* Also you were not the only one who had her post edited; the author of the question had the same happen to him.

**Regarding the "suspension threat":** That's part of a normal workflow, one that you'll find in most, if not all, online communities. Step 1 is "Try to de-escalate the situation", Step 2 (takes place if de-escalating doesn't work) is temporarily suspending the user causing the problem (to let them cool down a bit).

So, to close this off, **Meagar did exactly what he should have done.** No harassment / oppression took place here (and definitely not based on gender!).

---

Regarding your last-paragraph-question (the other part of your question reads like a rant):

Sorry for having to put it like this, but growing a thicker skin would come in quite handy here. Most users of Stack Overflow are male (that doesn't automatically mean we devalue women here...); that's true, but I don't care if male or female, why would I? I'm here because I'm a programmer. I do not watch out for gender-specific terms while writing, simply because I do not see any value in doing so.

If you feel like it, feel free to comment on questions using gender-specific language, or edit it out (as long as you do not deface the original question!). You do have the necessary privilege after all.

Comment: Hey, this answer is great! Thank you for putting the effort in it, it describes the situation very well (especially for people that came here without knowing what happened) (I know that you usually just express this with an upvote, but I'm sorry I had to say something more than an upvote ;))

Comment: Seth, this is a pretty thoughtful post, and you worked hard to express respect for the OP.  Might you consider cutting the opening section?  Leading with "Here we go" and "sick of it" makes it seem like you're completely dismissing the OP's experience out of hand. You then go on to make clear you haven't, and are actually sympathetic, but it's undermined by the opener, IMO.

Comment: @Jaydles You're right :) I changed it, it should be better now (less ranty, more introductory).

Comment: Thanks! That's much better (and I think much more in line with your intended tone).  IMO, It makes it a lot easier for a reader to consider your other points fairly.

Comment: @Jaydles I think the original introduction scared a good amount of potential readers away ("I'm not going to read *yet another* rant.") :p And yes, it does make the whole thing flow better.

Answer (score 18):

We generally like to remove everything not directly related to the question at hand from both questions and answers. That has nothing to do with gender. The only thing that matters in that context is if the part considered for removal is an integral part of the question or answer. If it is not, it's noise and needs to go.

We remove things like "Thanks" or "I'm a beginner so ..." all the time from questions. In fact it is expected that you do that when editing a post.

As important as gender issues are, this is not an outlet for them. We're a strictly technical Q/A site.

What happened in your case is that someone removed unnecessary noise from both the question and answer, which is entirely expected and okay.

In regards to "covering it all up" the same principle applies to comments. Noise or no longer relevant comments get removed. Comments in general are not permanent anyway, so they get deleted for varieties of reasons all the time.

Comment: OK so users that are struggling should do what? Just suck it up and deal with it? This is the solution? Why is no one addressing my actual question?

Comment: @naomik What exactly are you struggling with? People not using gender neutral language? With all due respect, the way to affect change in that is not to put edits or comments next to technical Q/A. Thats a change that will have to come over time, and pointing it out in answers or questions is adding noise to our technical Q/A which we don't want.

Comment: @naomik You can always edit out or neutralize "You guys" or similar phrases in the larger context of a proper edit that fixes other issues of the post, too, if you feel so inclined.

Answer (score 18):

*@meagar removed the gender exclusive language from the question and my playful remark in my answer. This effectively removes my voice as a user.*

We could as easily insert another (more powerful, IMO) interpretation here: @meager removed the gender exclusive language, and as a consequence your remark that was no longer necessary. Both reduced fluff. 
You have no idea why @meager removed those texts, and you are reacting to your own interpretation of that (No offense: that is what all people do).

The same goes for *@meagar's actions trivialize my efforts and bury a serious issue that I encounter very frequently.* Again, **your conclusion/interpretation**. Who knows what @meager intended? He/she could as well be sensitive to gender exclusive language and removed it because of that (I sometimes do that as well.)

You are completely right stating *it's so ingrained in user language that it often goes by completely undetected*, but the purpose of this site is not to educate people socially (which you yourself said: *I don't expect StackOverflow to be a forum for societal issues* and *I know SO is not my bulletin board for social justice*).

Obviously @meager pushed a button with you: *@meagar's actions have harmed me*, *Female user discriminated against and silenced*, *the community to benefit at my expense*, and *threaten to suspend me*. Maybe it's time to step back and inspect your reaction<sup>*</sup>. That reaction is not *wrong*, but it costs you.
On a practical level that could mean: Step back from your keyboard now. Come back tomorrow. Your discussion *is* welcomed although people may not agree.

<sup>* Like you boldfacing your final paragraph right now. Why do you insist that you are not getting heard?</sup>

Answer (score 10):

> Here's how I get to see it: User solicits help of of male community.
>   User receives help from 30k reputation female user. Female user nudges
>   that non-males can answer too. SO moderators edit her answer to leave
>   the 99% of the text that serves SO's purpose. Male user got what he
>   came for. Female user discriminated against and silenced. All future
>   visitors blind/ignorant to the abuse.

Note, I am not active on SO, I am a mod at Money.SE. The issue above could happen at any stack. You are fighting the wrong battle. There's misogyny all around us. It's not just worth fighting against, it's imperative that we all take a role in eliminating it.

SE aspires to a high signal to noise ratio (STNR). As an example, a widow asks a finance question, and we go to Meta for the fact that good answers also contain the words, "Sorry for your loss" or other words of comfort, which of course are non-financial. Members advocate for a board that's pretty tight on how we compose answers and to aim to post only what might be appropriate for a (published) scholarly work.

In that scenario, if a great answer were left and the paragraph about how "my dad died under similar circumstances and I feel your pain" were removed, that wouldn't mean the mod was heartless, or glad the deceased is gone. It's just abiding by the standards of the board.

The fact that English tends toward the male pronoun is an issue, no doubt. And it may be appropriate to ask questions about it at English.SE. Certainly appropriate to bring it up in the real world. On SO, the [be nice policy](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) serves to keep people treated kindly, but don't confuse STNR with censorship or misogyny. That would be unfair to the members who embrace diversity, and would jump to edit/delete anything offensive.

Comment: Its worth noting that so much as a disparaging remark even in jest is usually _very_ quickly removed from nearly anywhere on the network. The time until offensive posts get edited or destroyed is measured in minutes, not hours.

Answer (score 9):

Adding another answer to so many answers. This is an issue that is near and dear to me, as the author of this post [Declining Numbers of Women in Programming, What Can SO do to Help?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309908/diminishing-numbers-of-women-in-programming-and-the-so-experience).

**Firstly:**

I would have edited out the reference to "guys" without even an edit comment about it, as it's obvious what the edit was and I'm lazy when it comes to writing edit reasons.

**Secondly:**

The joke:

> This would've been easier if I was a boy

These type of jokes are best kept on facebook. They have no place on SO. Trust me, I get it, but it's so important to bite the tongue on here. Not as a woman as a SO user, we all need to maintain a level of professionalism. I would've edited that comment out if I saw it.

**Thirdly :**

Post vandalisation is not the way to protest. That is something we're always trying to clean up. It's something we deal with in problem users, or people experiencing rage fits. You're better than that. You're a high rep user and have been on the site for many years. It would've been better to come here in the first instance.

**Fourthly - Choose Your Battles:**

I'm not saying you or anyone else, have to do this. This is how I manage and sometimes don't manage.

I choose my battles on SE. I don't always correct people if they think I'm a man and even have a female avatar. In some cultures people seem to refer to anyone assisting them as "Sir". I let it go. Mainly because there's enough noise in comments as it is. If someone refers to me as "man" or a "bloke" in chat, I will correct them.

Having said that. I've had huge arguments in chat, where I lost my temper over gender issues and that the "he" should really only be used if you know for sure that the person is indeed male.

The thing I love about SO, is there are so many intelligent men on the site, who love and support women in programming. I need to remember this when I get worked up or embroiled in an argument in chat, that there are plenty of supportive people, they tend to not be as loud as the people making objections.

**Fifthfly** ;)

The whole gender thing is not limited to SO and as a whole SO does pretty well in protecting women's rights. The issue of a male majority is not the fault of SO, but as a community we can ask, how can we do it better than the rest?

The biggest issue on here, is when a woman corrects a user about her gender, I'd like to see the user take that correction  graciously. We all come from different cultural backgrounds. So sometimes a way of wording something may be perceived as a challenge into the user's psyche and be blown way out of proportion. For example:

Recently a woman said to another user, words to the effect: " I am a woman, don't disrespect my gender" Something like that. Anyway, the other user took it out of hand as an insult, when it appeared to be a simple correction, maybe not worded in the best way. It is simpler to just say nothing or continue then with addressing the he as a she.

There's too much dust blown up about gender. Women have a right to be referred to as a "she" or "her", not "he" or "him" and it's really as simple as that. It would be great to see the members of this site lead by example on this issue.

We are such a pedantic lot on this site, it's like being in a court room sometimes the amount of debate that can ensue over technicalities. I implore people to move on more easily and **Choose Your Battles**. It's a programming site. If a woman corrects you. Accept it, move on.

**Sixly:** *omg will these numbers ever end*

My attitude is this. My gender is irrelevant as a programmer. I don't like being called out as a  woman, for example: Can I have a "woman's perspective on this?" My gender on the site is irrelevant, except within specific meta discussions tagged [gender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gender).

That aside, I'm here to share and improve my programming skills and assist in moderating the site.

It will be good when societies can regard a person as a person and the differentiation of gender and abilities only applies where it should, with childbirth and breastfeeding. Currently only women can do this and these activities have nothing to do with programming.

---

Interesting experience and an example of how I now handle things.

Went into chat after writing this and was faced with an off and inappropriate comment. Flagged the comment, this then caused a great discussion about the comment being flagged and then a thread of disgusting comments, which I continued to flag. I went to the Tavern and pinged [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9).

> [There's some disgusting people going out of there way to make women feel demoralised](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5257236#5257236)

This also got the attention of other users and the comments were deleted.

I then pinged the RO:

> [@rene can you have a look at the transcript and maybe have a look at who has RO privileges here. interesting since I just sang SO praises here If I want to go to a pub and put up with low brow crap I would do that. I'm very unhappy to say the least](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/32855717#32855717)

This is a prime example of what I was saying:

> [@πάνταῥεῖ I feel like some people have a built-in blacklist in their minds triggering a flag immediately without looking at the context…](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/32855661#32855661)

If someone starts talking about *tits* in a chat room. I'm the only woman in the room. How am I supposed to feel? And why is it that people defend this behaviour and degrade the people flagging this type of chat?

It's important to remember there will always be people supporting good behaviour:

> [We don't need to provoke stuff here.](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/32855693#32855693)

I stay quiet and flag, get support if needed and then will make a comment. This keeps me from getting more upset and becoming embroiled in an argument and becoming part of the problem of lowering the professionalism on the site.

Comment: I hear that there are drugs that men can take that cause them to lactate... just saying.

Comment: @yellowantphil exactly! That's why I said yet. They'd want to make sure they have a chest wax... just saying ;)

Comment: Note that "Sir" is sometimes a language quirk. We don't have gender specific pronouns in Tagalog (Filipino), so "Po" implies a respectful way to address either gender. But as you're thinking in one language and writing in another, it sometimes just comes out that way. Sometimes my wife will say "his" when speaking in the possessive sense regarding my daughter, and it's just a manifestation of that - she just grabbed the wrong word while being in thought (and she's more fluent than many native English speakers). Many other languages and dialects all over Asia share this similarity.

Comment: @TimPost yep I suspected that, which is why I don't correct it, and don't worry about comments in posts. Chat is a different thing, when you can get a feel for someone's level of English skills.

Comment: Oh hey yvette :) expected an answer from you too. Great answer.

Comment: @ArdaÖzkal thanks. Yes I have a rep for supporting women in programming.

Comment: Good to see you chimed in! (I linked your question in the comments of my answer above, and reread it and some of the answers yesterday. I was glad to see it still read to me as a high quality discussion of the gender issue. I'm glad to see your answer here is just as well written and thought out.)

Comment: @Kendra thanks for the feedback, I value that.

Answer (score 8):

I can understand how terrible it feels to be discriminated...

...but you are not being discriminated.

## "Guy" is not gender specific.

[Guy is gender-neutral when talking about a group of people.](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/guy)

> 1.1 (guy) People of either sex

## Reason of removal of gender specific parts

SEN is a platform where everyone is considered equal.

We don't care about your gender, your age (ALA you are over 13, due to COPPA), your nationality, your political views, your skin color etc etc. We care about your knowledge and contributions.

This was why the gender specific language was removed and only the relevant part was left, as you said:

> SO moderators edit her answer to leave the 99% of the text that serves SO's purpose.

## Why does it matter?

This part might be a bit harsh. Sorry in advance.

Why does it matter if someone thinks that you are a man?

Why the hell do genders even matter anymore? What year is this? Every healthy person is capable of doing (pretty much) anything other gender can do. Genders only matter when you are trying to find someone to date with etc. Stack is not a dating site. It shouldn't matter, it doesn't matter.

## You trying to remove your answer and getting threatened to be suspended

Your answers are not *your* answers. If you answer and want complete control over it, please go start a programming blog or something. On StackExchange, as I said above, we care about information, not other irrelevant stuff.

Your answers help people. You can't just remove it. Suspension is indeed the result of trying to remove an answer for irrelevant reasons.

## A personal note.

Someone assuming you are the other gender is nothing. I recommend you to stay off the less-moderated parts of internet.

Comment: Don't get me wrong. I'm a feminist (not of the, uhm, more unstable ones, but the ones that consider women and men equal). I think that there are bigger problems than "he assumed I'm a guy". I agree that it sucks, but let's take care of the worse parts first, ok? This just seems overkill right now.

Comment: Ah, unsolicited life lessons. This is certainly what we lacked in this thread.

Comment: A minor point of difference: guys isn't _yet_ gender neutral. It may be getting there, but here in the UK, "hi guys" works with a group of any gender, but "those guys over there" sounds, to my ears, specifically male. I am, I confess, not sure why - and I appreciate this may be different in other English-speaking countries.

Comment: @halfer the best way to make it more gender neutral is using and accepting it as gender neutral.

Comment: @ArdaÖzkal: to a point, but if language is merely an encoding of information, the meaning that is carried is what the listener believes was meant. A group of well-meaning redefiners can only speed this up so much, and in the interim, the effect may be understood as discriminatory.

Comment: Re: *""Guy" is not gender specific."*. That may only be true in a particular cultural context: North American (and still then restricted to particular circumstances (less formal ones?)). That is, that word may never be used for that purpose anywhere else (some other words or expression may be used instead). I could be wrong; I am geographically challenged.

Comment: @PeterMortensen SE is an American company fwiw

Comment: @ArdaÖzkal - I am male, but am a feminist. i.e. look at the definition, I've vote, advocate, preach for all it really means. I am in a high school, so age 14-18 people. After this question here came up, I asked 3 girls if 'Guys' was a bad way to refer to multiple people in the room who happen to be all girls. They said that no one would think it strange, it's non-gender specific. When I hear a girl or woman use it that same way, it becomes a non-issue. Interesting that Turkey (you) agree, but UK, above, doesn't. English is a strange language.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I'm having a difficulty understanding your comment. Are you talking about me or yourself in the first part (the part before "After this question here came up")? If you are talking about yourself... I thought that you were older. Whatever. If you are talking about me, I don't get what you mean on that part. (Also, as visible on my [network profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/3986488/), I'm 15, (turning 16 next month so I consider 16, whatever))

Comment: Sorry, I am 53 and work in a high school. The rest just agreed with you on the use of "guys" being non gender specific. Overheard my 17 yr old daughter use "guys" tonight when referring to her and 4 female friends getting together. Last I appreciated your first comment above, there are bigger issues, equal rights across the world, equal pay in the US is still an issue, etc.

Comment: I'd like to note down that nearly after a year after posting this, I do not agree with everything I said on this post, especially on "Why does it matter?", "A personal note." parts or stuff like "irrelevant stuff". I now believe that misgendering is a problem, but my point about the rest stands ("guys" is gender neutral).

Answer (score 2):

I'll post my answer because it'll just take too many comments.

First off, as with most answers and comments have said, what was removed from your answer was *noise*; it is normal procedure for *anyone* with editing privileges to edit out noise. You have admitted yourself that the line that was removed from your answer, the *noise* was in reply to something from the question which too was *noise*. Now if the noise from the question was removed, aside from looking like weren't doing their volunteer job properly, your noise would have made no sense<sup>1</sup>.

Your reaction was to then try and delete the answer. At the time it was the accepted answer which caused you then opt to vandalize the question. As already pointed out by others, it is frowned upon<sup>2</sup>.

@Meagar then warned you that you risk suspension because of your vandalization of your answer. I determine this because the comment talked about self-destruction. The common action of users who self-destruct is to remove all their question/answers either by deleting them or vandalizing them to remove all content. @Meagar then deletes a bunch of comments.

Your verdict? Mod Abuse! **Slams fist on table** Censorship! **Slams fist on table**

Of course this is hardly the case. Others have already explained about the edits in which should be noted that anyone can submit an edit and some people can [edit without approval](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) (the poster included regardless of rep), so it didn't need to be a mod to set this off. The comment removal is because

> Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer.

> Comments are seen as ephemeral on Stack Exchange. They are not the main content. The only purpose of comments is to provide feedback to a question or answer with the goal of improving it.

Sources: [Privileges - Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) & [Mods deleting comments because they don't agree - Accepted Answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278517/1028804)

Moderators are the only people who can delete other people's comments, so I get the feeling the moderator abuse and censorship charges would have also included conspiracy if a user edited the question and a moderator deleted the comments.

If not, would you have reacted the same if this was the case? Is not why? A moderator is just like any other user, but with the ability to deal with more of the crap we don't see on the surface. (Who do you think those moderator attention flags go to?)

---

Now you may have noticed the <sup>1</sup> and <sup>2</sup>, and I do this to point out something from [your answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334457/1028804):

> I often consider future visitors in my question responses

Your actions contradict this. First off, what of the future visitors you would have impacted from your vandalization of your answer had it been successful?

Regarding <sup>2</sup>:
The main thing though is that if you did consider future visitors then think about your "playful remark" (regarding <sup>1</sup>). I only believe it was playful because that is what you said. I am the kind of person who sometimes don't get these little jokes, hell a while back I believed *"tl;dr"* meant *"this post is too long so don't read it"*

Looking at the line by itself

> This would've been easier if I was a boy

What does this mean? Would laravel be harder to understand if I was a girl? Is it because I am a boy (debatable<sup>3</sup>) that I understand PHP as well as I do? (Also debatable).

Even if I understood by myself that this line as a playful remark in response to something in the question, when this was removed from the question your playful remark no longer has this "playful" aspect to it and a future visitor may have been offended, because the context is gone.

---

Ideally you should be going through Stack Overflow assuming that no one knows your sex or gender and don't care either way. If they refer to *you* incorrectly (in comments) kindly correct them if it bothers you that much, if not ignore it. If you see this in questions or answers, do what @meagar did and edit it, more than likely its noise with no reason to be in the post and won't affect it.

---

<sup>3: I am a male, but I consider myself as a maiden.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Guys is gender neutral at this point and gender has nothing to do with how you manipulate arrays in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add a general note of encouragement, even if the final *Meta* answer about editing out "voice" is not the one you are looking for. Hope it is of some help.

A number of answers here have addressed the main question, and I agree with the broad position expressed thus far, which is that off-topic material does not belong in posts. I am a frequent editor and regularly remove thanks, salutations, urgent begging, deadlines, religious material, hopes that the post is clear or that someone can answer. However, whilst I try to respect the opinion of people who are approaching the community in good faith, we are firmly anti-fluff here, even when that material is intended to serve a social good.

I do take issue sometimes with the tone expressed on *Meta* about gender<sup>†</sup> - this community *is* male dominated, and if men are lining up to tell you you're not being discriminated against, I can see how that is potentially problematic. For what is worth - and I'm afraid I am offering another male opinion on the matter - I do think the gender-positive view emanating from Stack Overflow Inc is genuine (and I am not usually given to say nice things about corporations). I also think it is great that we get this opportunity to discuss this with a major tech company, given that most do not even permit this small window into their day-to-day running.

It is possible that the slow transformation in attitudes towards gender equality, at least in this little corner of the internet, might be served by finding gender-specific phrases and ironing them out. You may, if you wish, add a note about why you have done this in the edit reason - I have added `Remove gender-specific language` in the past, and the sky did not fall in! Bear in mind though that "guys", to take the usual example, is very common on the site, and I might gently advise against taking on too great an editing burden. That way leads to burnt-out, however good the intentions are.

Note that if you do choose to edit posts in this way, it is expected that you improve all obvious issues, rather than just your bugbears; my pet peeve is begging and pleading, but when I edit, I do really see the value in improving as much as possible.

I'd also add that gender specificity is seen in different ways around the world. Where you see "sir", this tends to be very common in India, where we have a lot of users, and this salutation is regarded as a form of great respect. In a country where "he" is still taught in schools as the gender-neutral form, "male by default" thinking still prevails. My view is that it is fine to amend these, but be gentle when you do so, since it can be greatly confusing to someone who may not have been exposed to much feminist philosophy. (I made the mistake of commenting to correct male-specific language from an Italian who had a very limited grasp of English, and I think I completely befuddled the poor chap, who was very apologetic nothwithstanding, and I end up achieving nothing).

Finally, and I may be teaching you to suck eggs at this point - have you considered furthering the gender/tech cause by aiding female-centric community groups, either by donating or helping? Girls Who Code (in the US) comes to mind, and there are sure to be similar initiatives in your region.

---

<sup>†</sup> Following on from a comment below, this remark may merit some further expansion. A popular view expressed here is that on *Meta*, we are emotionless automatons in the best possible way - we analyse proposals, we leave our flaws at the door, we almost disconnect from our physicality - and we are certainly not hampered by bias or subconscious motivation.

But, of course, that's not the real world we live in. If someone suggests that the gender-specific language (and the genderised assumptions behind them) feels exclusionary, we automatons do not comprehend, for we have not experienced such exclusion. Consciously or otherwise, we then respond as if it is not possible for a reasonable person to feel excluded, or that a person who felt excluded is unnecessarily sensitive.

We don't merely say they are wrong to feel such things, but that their concern is **completely and utterly irrelevant** on Meta. For us automatons, **it's that simple**, and some are even **sick of this!** We demand to know **why it matters if someone thinks that you are a man!** You are **not being discriminated against**! Of course, **"guys" is gender neutral** anyway! (with apologies to the authors, who do not intend to invalidate another person's experience).

Indeed, we come quite close to being offended - as much as our automaton souls will allow, at any rate - that something as illogical as *discrimination* might have crept into the circuits of our writing.

And so it is by this process that a person experiencing exclusion may, when they raise their head above the parapet, experience a response from the primary in-group that is itself exclusionary, thus worsening the problem. Of course, an in-group automaton could argue that this strategy could be used to argue anything, to which I tend to say: is an accommodation available that does not apply a punitive cost to the in-group? If the answer is yes - for example in the form of not using gendered language - maybe this is acceptable, even if in-group automatons do not understand the reasons for being asked to do so.

Comment: I appreciate your thoughtful and tactful reply. fwiw, I try to be very understanding a gender-exclusive language and I've never *ever* responded in an angry manner toward another individual for using such language. I operate under the illusion that everyone has good intentions even if that sometimes means I give an undeserving person the benefit of the doubt. I know I would be completely ineffective if I appeared to be the scathing, raging feminist type. ...

Comment: ... I have not considered getting involved with female communities – I'm not totally sure why. I've never been extroverted enough to feel like I'd ever belong in any community, tbh. Despite what anyone here would believe about me, it took a lot of courage to face my peers when I felt something objectionable was happening.

Comment: You're welcome @naomik. I wonder if volunteering to teach children coding would appeal to you? There'd be some great gender modelling for the girls, and anyway, kids can sometimes be easier to work with than adults `:-)`. Here in the UK, we have [Code Club](http://codeclub.org.uk/) that organises such volunteering, and I'd expect there are similar organisations elsewhere.

Comment: Honestly the thought of being a role model gives me a lot of anxiety. I'm not entirely sure why. I constantly feel like a fraud amongst peers and I very rarely feel a sense of belonging – anywhere, really. This isn't meant to solicit pity, it's just the truth about me. Especially after this post here, I really feel like I don't have much to lose.

Comment: The other component to that might be selfishness – I'm always striving to learn more and I feel like I would be stifling my own personal development by teaching elementary topics to beginners. It's much more the anxiety aspect tho. Probably 70/30 anxiety/selfishness :S

Comment: _"I do take issue sometimes with the tone expressed on Meta about gender"_ The tone that _gender_ is completely and utterly __irrelevant__ on this site? What issue could one have with a online community where it doesn't matter what gender you are?

Comment: @naomik: my guess is that your level of learning is significantly ahead of your peer group, given your S/O score and GitHub profile. You could, if you wish, take some time off from learning without harming your skills marketability. Of course I can't know if teaching is suitable for you, but small groups is a good way to start.

Comment: (...and [this article](https://davidwalsh.name/impostor-syndrome) is pretty good too. Yeah, he works for Mozilla).

Comment: @Cerbrus: thanks, I've added some opinion material to try to answer that, I hope it helps.

Comment: @halfer: _"A popular view expressed here is that on Meta, we are emotionless automatons in the best possible way"_ You are ___completely___ missing the point of _"gender doesn't matter"_. We are not emotionless. It's just that gender is _literally_ irrelevant.

Comment: @Cerbrus: I do see your point, but I think your view is wrong. Sure, gender should not matter here. But when a conversation about gender is drowned out by "no, that does not matter here" - with lots of bold font - then maybe it does. We will probably just have to agree to disagree! `:-)`

Comment: _"when a conversation about gender..."_ A conversation we shouldn't be having on here in the first place. ___That___ is why people are saying it __does not__ matter here. That subject isn't suddenly relevant to meta, if a users suddenly makes something completely unrelated about "gender". Screaming "Gender discrimination!" doesn't make it gender discrimination.

Comment: I agree with your last sentence @Cerbrus. I'd make the opposite case too, which is probably my main theme: screaming "not gender discrimination" does not make it not gender discrimination.

Comment: However, in this specific case, the OP _made it about_ gender discrimination.

Comment: @halfer Similarly, screaming "Gender discrimination" when its not doesn't suddenly make it, and doing that makes people dislike you intensely, and when push comes to shove about actual discrimination, people often then push it aside, because you misrepresented the first time.

Comment: @Cerbrus: ah, I see your point. In relation to the moderation in this specific case, I agree with you; in relation to the general theme about genderised language, I agree with the OP.

Comment: _"the general theme about genderised language"_ may be an issue, but not an issue for SO. Once again, gender is irrelevant here.

Comment: @Cerbrus: that may be the nub of our disagreement. I think that if gendered language is creeping onto SO, the discussion absolutely belongs on Meta SO. Again, thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score -27):

There are three kind of people that would use this kind of discrimination:

1. Ignorants
2. Wrongers
3. Ill-intentioned

The first category is hard to educate, you can leave messages/comments, but likely they won't give a damn and pursuit only their happiness.

The second category can indeed be educated, you can do this by leaving educational comments when editing their posts, as others have suggested.

The third category should not even be present on this site, but if so, their content will likely be removed during moderation (by regular users via flags/votes, or by moderators).

Your point is a valid one though, there are sexists among us, however spamming like you did way won't help you or the receiver. There is a chance people that you attack this way will feel too ashamed to even ask another question on this site again. Have you thought about those?

Comment: I'm sorry, what person did I spam/attack?

Comment: @naomik I was referring to the person you were responding to. Maybe "attack" is a little bit forced in this context, still a passive-aggressive tone doesn't guarantee the effect you'd expect.

Comment: @Cristik: There wasn't any discrimination in the first place. The OP of that question never said women couldn't answer. Altogether, this answer is just a rant that's hardly based in reality.

Comment: @Cerbrus The OP in discussion might fit into the second category from my answer - "wrongers", as he might have not realize that using appellatives like "guys" might offend other people. For those ones, editing the post with an explanatory message, as suggested, would suffice. The other two categories  are hard to educate, so simply removing the problematic parts from their content should suffice.

Answer (score -27):

## The don't call it the "edit" button for nothing

Many here are saying things to the effect of: "@meager's decision was *objective*: there are rules against off-topic content and he was enforcing them." I disagree that his actions were nothing more than "objectively enforcing the rules."

To wit: I see his choice to remove this particular piece of OT content as **editorializing**, i.e. changing the content to reflect or protect a certain viewpoint.

Just as a newspaper editor's choices of which stories to run and which to drop is a reflection of their views, *moderators' choices of which "off-topic" content to remove reflects their views*. The fact that this 9 word comment was singled out for removal among the sea of off-topic content on SO says volumes about the values of the moderating team here (I'm not going to single out @meager as he seems to have the support of the whole team).

My point? **Stop trying to pretend this decisions was a mechanical application of a set of clear-cut instructions! It was EDITORIALIZING.**

We can disagree about whether this was a good editorial judgement call, but claiming there was no judgement call at all is just baloney. You made a decision: own it!!

## "objectively enforcing site rules" "that's always how it is"

I do not believe these rules are universally & evenly applied. Here's *a few* examples of off-topic content that mods saw fit to leave intact:

> I preface this by saying my Javascript experience is very weak. Lots of jQuery, very little real comprehension.

How many books the user read has no impact how prototypal inheritance works in JS, and as @madara-uchiha puts it “The visitor from Google coming to read a question and its answer doesn't care [how many books you read]”: off topic [How to better understand Coffeescript/JavaScript mixins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728074/coffeescript-javascript-mixins-idiot-seeking-explanation)

> “I am recording video for my church…

immaterial, off topic [What format should I convert my home video to for web and mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171575/what-format-should-i-convert-my-home-video-to-for-web-and-mobile)

> I was handed an software doc (or what passes for proper documentation nowadays). Much to my chagrin, it might as well have been gently used piece of toilet paper from the men's room.

off topic: Visitor from google didn’t come for wry scatological humor. [How would I translate this C# code into PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189083/how-would-i-translate-this-c-sharp-code-into-php-solve-the-mystery-of-someones)

> This leads to an interesting question: "Is :kate_upton an object?" Yes, :kate_upton has been objectified in Ruby (as well as other places), but your feminist friends may not want to hear that. They may, however, mellow out if you let them know that everything in Ruby are equally objects (except blocks, and a few other things)

off topic, politically charged, and specifically hostile towards women. The trifecta! https://stackoverflow.com/a/23587486/146406

> I hired a guy to finish everything concerning s3, but he does not know how to download file.

Your employee relationships are not relevant to the question, off topic

> That idiot being me

user's intellectual capacity is off topic [Can anybody explain OAuth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514579/can-anybody-explain-oauth-to-an-idiot)

> First of all, yes i have searched this site for answers. I have searched for HOURS.

Visitor from google doesn’t care how long you searched, they just want the answer [AWS ec2 SSH permission denied (publickey)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027811/aws-ec2-ssh-permission-denied-publickey)

> My cursor fell upon the "Empty Trash" menu option like the cold lid of a casket.
>
> I don't think Flash ever recovered. To this day it still clings to the
>   memory of Jenine. Her old, imperfect definitions still float through
>   my project like abandoned ghosts. Whenever I force Flash to compile,
>   it still lovingly inserts her into my movie, nestling her definition
>   in amongst the other, living classes, like a small shrine. I wonder if
>   they can see her.

wat? **100k views, no moderator cleanup**. [Flash CS4 refuses to let go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193953/flash-cs4-refuses-to-let-go)

## "...did you ever catch *all* the fish?"

Of course not: I understand that mods will not catch everything and must pick their battles. This is precisely why I wonder, **why did mods choose to pick this particular battle**, and not any of those above?

*content warning: the following few lines contains snark*:

I ran some analysis on naomik's comment and the results were shattering:

```
$ echo "This would've been easier if I was a boy" | wc -w
   9
```

**The comment is a total of 9 words**. Compare that to the Flash novella above. Why was the 9 word comment singled out and that one left alone? "The mods just missed it..." With 100k+ views? I don't think so. Mods definitely saw that post & decided to leave it alone. The bizarre girlfriend narrative made the story humorous but to claim it was necessary in relating the question would be ridiculous: it obfuscated more than it clarified & served no purpose but humor.

So why was naomik's 9 word comment (prefacing her **ludicrously technically detailed answer**) singled out?

## [Feelings... nothing more than feelings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AnFxAnbJD8A)

- Q: Why was this post singled out for editing on the grounds of "off-topicness" and not others?
- A: Because this one gently calls attention to sexism, and **that might hurt someone's feelings**.

The post was edited to protect someone's feelings. But who's?

- Q: Who is going to be offended by a comment poking fun at someone for assuming only "guys" answer questions on SO?
- A: Insecure and/or sexist men.

## Conclusion: All posts are handled equally. Some are just handled more equally than others.

If all OT content was handled equally, I wouldn't have been able to easily find so many examples (see above). The OT content rule is flexible, subjective, and very much up to the Mods' discretions.

@meager & the Mod team chose to invoke the "off-topic content" rule to remove a comment that might have been offensive to men who don't want to think about implicit sexist language. They do not remove all instances of "guys" across SO because the gendered language isn't the issue to them: the issue was that **someone pointed it out**, and pointing out this pervasive aspect of the SO culture might hurt some men's feelings. Sad!

Comment: you seem to be assuming that the elected moderators (and employees who moderate) see and moderate every single post.

Comment: @KevinB I addressed your concern explicitly in my post. See: "...did you ever catch *all* the fish?" above, a reference to a joke that while a fisherman or woman constantly works at catching fish, they never catch *all* the fish. Does that clarify that I understand moderators will not see every post? See also, above: '"The mods just missed it..." With 100k+ views? I don't think so.'

Comment: No, i did read that part. If you truly meant it though, then the rest of your post seems pretty contradictory.

Comment: This is asinine, and from start to finish it is based on a completely false representation of the facts. I "picked" this battle **because it was flagged**. For the umpteenth time, and I don't know why we have to keep explaining this, moderators are not selectively protecting some objectionable content while removing other content until **you can prove that we're systematically ignoring some flags and responding to others**.  We aren't viewing an even sampling of posts and choosing to act on some but not others, **we are responding to flags**. If you find bad content, just **flag it**.

Comment: The difference between the off-topic material in question and the off-topic material that "the mods saw fit to leave intact" is that the former _was flagged_ (as meagar says above), and had the (realized) potential to cause a string of nasty comments, answer vandalism, and a contentious post on Meta. If you think those other off-topic bits are so bad, either edit them, suggest edits, or flag them.

Comment: have you tried, i don't know, making or even suggesting an edit on *any* of the posts you point out that you believe stuff should be removed? have they been rejected? was the reason for the rejection supportive of your claims? unless another's [suggestion history](http://stackoverflow.com/users/146406/sequoia-mcdowell?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) hides rejected edits the answer is no as not a single one of the 8 posts you mention appear in your list of 8 suggestions.

Comment: (cont.) mods don't moderate every post, they help with the rest of the community, including you. so if you want to blame the *just* mods for not making edits where you see them then you should take some of the blame for not suggesting the edits either

Comment: I'm pleased that you're willing to speak up for gender equality, but as a man who tries to do the same, I nevertheless think this post could have been a bit more, erm, gentle and constructive. I think naomik was right to raise the issue of genderised language on Meta, but IMO that does not mean that moderator action in response to off-topic material is unfairly biased.

Comment: LOL that's funny...... genuinely funny. They removed it because other people flagged it to point them to it. There is NOTHING else at play here. Before you continue complaining, I would suggest for you to FLAG all the posts you linked here and see how they are acted upon. If the same type of off-topicness, flagged the same way, doesn't get handled the same way.... we have a problem.

Comment: @meager what was the answer flagged for (i.e. which of the radio button choices was picked)?

Comment: @ everyone asking me to flag the questions in question: will do! I've started flagging already & as @patrice suggests, mod action will show whether there's a problem or not :)

Comment: Btw the IDEAL solution is to edit, not flag these. But yeah

Comment: Can anyone tell me what the answer was flagged as? I'm not sure if I have the privs to see that but it seems material to the discussion.

Comment: @sequoiamcdowell are you asking what the original flag was that brought meagar to my answer? I suppose I'm curious to know the flag reason, too.

Comment: @meagar you are a moderator precisely to **use your judgement**. You don't have to act on every flag. You can just as well say "eh... this is one sentence in a really long, detailed answer. I don't think editing is warranted here." In contrast, "I must, I have an *Obligation*, to respond to flags!!" is the *shirking* of your responsibility to exercise judgement. If mod judgement were not a key part of this process, flaggers could just edit the post themselves. If a NLP script could detect OT content, we wouldn't need mods. This issue is about a *bad judgment call*.

Comment: @sequoiamcdowell Disagree.

Comment: @meagar ah, you're here! :) Can you tell us why the answer was originally flagged, i.e. which of the radio options for flag reason was picked?

Comment: @sequoiamcdowell It wasn't, naomik's comment ("probably too hard for girls to answer, tho") on the question were flagged as "rude or abusive".

Comment: @sequoiamcdowell I have time for a slightly longer response now, so: You are again wrong, and ignorant of how the site works, and of my duties as a moderator. The biggest part of my job is handling flags in the flag queue. That's *most* of a moderator's duty.  At the very least, I can choose to reject some flags as invalid, but nearly the *whole point of my being here* is to act on flags. What kind of message would I be sending if somebody flagged *"probably too hard for girls to answer, tho"* as offensive, and I *declined* the flag?

Comment: @sequoiamcdowell I would urge you, in the future, to take a few minutes and try to gather at least *some* of the facts before making sweeping allegations about the conduct of others. You've been factually wrong at virtually ever turn here, basing your argument on incorrect assumptions about the events and motives. In the process you've accused me of either being or acting to protect "insecure and/or sexist men", accused me of making "bad judgment calls", and implied that there is some kind of systematic misogyny in how moderators respond to flags, all ridiculous and all highly insulting.

Comment: @meager so it was a comment that was flagged, not the answer itself? Was the answer flagged?

Comment: @sequoiamcdowell: I suggest you read meagar's replies to your question again: _"Can you tell us why the answer was originally flagged?"_ - _"It wasn't, naomik's comment was flagged"_. It's quite clear what _Was_ and what _wasn't_ flagged.

Answer (score -52):

I think it's rather scary that a post about gender equality gets so many down votes. I'd say that clearly shows that there's a problem. This post isn't saying anything upsetting, it's simply stating that we should try to include everyone. But clearly people don't like that. Or why would you otherwise down vote this?

To say that SO removes noise is simply not true. If you're going to remove all noise remove all gender-exclusive language as well. But that's not done. Instead SO selectively removes the noise it doesn't like. It's probably not something that's done intentionally. Moderators are removing what they see, no one is perfect an no one can see everything. But here a moderator clearly removed gender-excluding language and didn't want to take a discussion about it. So raising a question around this can't be that bad. Can it? Do we want an SO where discussing equality isn't ok?

Thirdly. To tell a female user to simply not disclose their gender as suggested here by πάντα ῥεῖ is an absurd solution. That can never be the solution to this. That means all females should hide? To not use their real name, to not post an avatar picture as others do. Is that really the SO we want? That would just push the the gender excluding even further.

Comment: Nothing to do with gender... All to do with "this isn't the place for such issues". 100%with you, no gender language should be something we strive for. I prefer mods to spend time on more useful things

Comment: "Nothing to do with gender... All to do with "this isn't the place for such issues"." Not sure I follow here. Are you saying that this post doesn't belong to Meta? Then were should it be? "Q&A for meta-discussion of the Stack Exchange family of Q&A websites" seems to suggest that Meta is exactly the place to put this.

Comment: What are you talking about? The issue here is ***NOT THE GENDER***, off-topic text was removed because it was off-topic, OP comes to meta and wants to discuss why her text was removed because we "censor" her, this is plainly not true and which is most likely the reason she is being down voted. If she instead had posted a question "Hey guys, I think there's a problem with X, what can we do about it?" The reception would most likely be different, please ***STOP TRYING TO MAKE IT A SOCIAL ISSUE.***

Comment: _"A post about gender equality gets so many down votes. I'd say that clearly shows that there's a problem."_ True, there ___is___ a problem. The problem is that the OP is making assumptions while the actions on their answer have ___nothing___ to do with gender.

Comment: @stenehall seems i wasn't cleae. I meant the basic assumptions of this question (that the removal of that text and what followed was based because of gender) are wrong. Now, if you encounter REAL gemder bias/harassment... Please flag/act appropriately. Not what happened. I'm sympathetic to the cause,but this isnt a battle for said cause. This is just an exercise in nonsense

Comment: @Cerbrus It might be true that the original action from the Mod wasn't based on gender. But if we want to change what kind of language is used and make people aware of what type of language they use. What else can we do?

Comment: @stenehall: _"But if we want to change what kind of language is used and make people aware of what type of language they use."_ As Madara answered, SO is not the place for that.

Comment: @stenehall 100% agree. However, on SO people from dozens of cultural environments and different socialization come together. I guess it is futile to discuss social issues here. You'll never get a consensus. It is really sad because this is such an important issue - but that is the reality.

Comment: @Patrice ok, I follow. While I can agree that it might not have been an ideal action from OP it at least was an action. So many just ignore it or try to explain it away. I've reported sexist harassment on SO before and it's been dealt with in a good way from SO. But sometimes you act for the right reason but in the wrong way.

Comment: @ftor then maybe SO could have clearer guidelines about what is ok and not ok and try to enforce them? Right now it seems like Mods remove what they consider noise without having specific reasons they can point to.

Comment: @stenehall and see, i have less issues with the action taken by OP on the main site than the tone of this post. There is an air of melodrama around the whole thing atm, which almost turns the whole discussion in a joke

Comment: @Patrice Also, want to note that I in no way meant that any of this have been harassment.

Comment: @stenehall: _"it might not have been an ideal action from OP"_: Making this about "gender" is far from an idea action. The edits were _never_ about gender.

Comment: @stenehall I think it's clear from the comments I inserted into the original post - the moderator was not unwilling to discuss it - it didn't belong in comments on the post. They gave clear instructions as to where it could be discussed - hence this post.

Comment: You'll also find that we're not "censoring" this question, nor have we locked/deleted it

Comment: @stenehall I guess so. But with the current organizational structure an improvement in this regard seems to be unlikely.

Comment: @JonClements A major problem with moving the discussion is that it gets hidden away. That the people that should read it doesn't and by that no improvement will come. Had the original noise not been removed the original poster would maybe have at least thought about it a second and then it would have been over. Removing the noise means that the poster never gets to reflex over it.

Comment: @stenehall everyone in that comment exchange was aware of its contents *before* it was removed and reasons were given as to why it was. It's been brought up again because the original question is missing context without it.

Comment: @JonClements Nor have I ever claimed that SO censor. I simply said that SO removes what they feel is noise. But far from all noise is removed and far from all gender excluding language is removed. And just removing the noise will never teach the people contributing to the noise what they did wrong. I.e. if the gender excluding language had been removed without the "This would've been easier if I was a boy ..." comment posted.

Comment: @stenehall: Are you volunteering for mod elections, when they open again? It's impossible to catch _all_ bad content. A humongous amount of it gets edited out already, but there will always be content that slips through the net.

Comment: @Cerbrus I've never said that the Mods are doing a bad job nor that they could catch everything. I specificly wrote "Moderators are removing what they see, no one is perfect an no one can see everything."

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what it is you are trying to say, you seem to complain that the moderators / SO team doesn't remove all noise, be it gender based or not, but then you proceed to say that you know that it's hard to find it all. If you know that, then what is your point? What are you trying to say?

Comment: @stenehall: You are accusing them of not being impartial, though: _"SO removes what they feel is noise. But far from all noise is removed"_ There, you ___are___ implying the mods are doing a bad job.

Comment: @Epodax I'm not trying to complain about the Mods nor SO in general. SO is a good platform. What Im trying to say is that there IS a gender problem on SO (as on most of the web). I don't see removing all gender excluding language as a solution since it isn't actually addressing the problem. Most people writing in a gender excluding way wont even realize it. So a short comment about it wouldn't be harmful. Since mods aren't perfect (noone is) it's impossible to remove all noise, the Mods will remove what they see, that is how it works.

Comment: @Epodax But if you look at this from the OPs view it might look different from what you all clearly see. She sees an gender excluding comment (and I can assure you that it's far from the only one on SO). She comments on it and the result is that it all is removed. At some point it gets to much. Was this voiced in an ideal way? Probably not. But it makes me sad that when someone feels mistreated and they actually dare voice it they're so hardly shut down by the community as OP have been in this thread.

Comment: @Epodax Someone suggested that a simple solution is to hide that she's a female. Noone but I commented on that. Nor did anyone actually support me when I said that's absurd. Instead people focus on "this wasn't gender based" and ignore everything else.

Comment: @Cerbrus I didn't mean for that to sound as I implied that they're doing a bad job. I'm sorry if it did. Noo ne is ever completely impartial, that's how we work. No one is perfect, we can't remove all noise. I simply meant to say that that is how it works. SO is a good place, but everything can always be better.

Comment: @stenehall so.. The OP is offended by the "guys" comment. A moderator, wanting to make sure no one is offended, removes the "guys". The comment in the OP's answer doesn't make sense now and is correctly removed. Honestly what should have happened here? It doesn't get removed: someone is offended. It gets removed: someone is offended. Feels like a lose-lose situation

Comment: @Patrice Sometimes there's no perfect solution to a situation. When there's two bad options I personally try to see what solution will help the most for the future. If both the answer and the comment is removed the same mistake will be repeated over and over again. If it's left, at least a few people might read it and see the problem with it and actually learn from it. For me SO is all about learning and getting better.

Comment: @stenehall: So, you'd rather _keep_ the noise in there so _some_ users _may_ learn something that's completely and utterly ___irrelevant___ to SO?

Comment: @Cerbrus Your view is that it's utterly irrelevant. For me if users feel bad it's not irrelevant. It's a problem within the community that should be addressed by the community. Since it happened in a thread it seems reasonable to at least start addressing it there, and then maybe move it to a better place. But if it's simply removed there won't be any improvement since no one will learn from it.

Comment: @stenehall: I feel bad because someone's offended by something that bears no relevance to the site. The point we need to get out there is that ___gender doesn't matter___. Not that we need to take excessive care not to "offend" ___anyone___.

Comment: Relevant: [404 - spine not found](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310549/404-spine-not-found)

Comment: @stenehall OK, I was wrong, there is a general consensus and it is reflected by the algo (blurring your response). I don't agree with it but that does not really matter.

Comment: @stenehall so the solution to offensive language is the LEAVE IT? Wait... Are you really serious there? If it offends someone let's leave it on the site so other people can learn from it? In any case Stack is not for these issues. At all. And even if it was, there can be lessons learned without letting the language on the site.

Comment: @Patrice I'm not saying I think all offensive language should be kept. But in this case it was a gender excluding comment probably done without bad intend. In that case it can serve as a teaching opportunity. When it's clearly sexist or rasist comments it's another matter. It's of course a blurry line between them, that's what makes it extra hard.

Comment: @stenehall but it's NOT Stack's place to be teaching these things. Just like the best zuchini bread recipe can teach me a lot, but shouldn't be in an answer, the whole "learning moment" here doesn't have to be on Stack. That's just how it is.

Comment: *"I think it's rather scary that a post about gender equality gets so many down votes. I'd say that clearly shows that there's a problem."* Just because you have an opinion, doesn't mean that everyone must agree with you. I've seen meta downvotes on a bunch of things. The question being about gender equality doesn't make it special. Votes on meta are based on agreement, and no one agrees that there was a social, gender issue as was presented in the question. That is all.

Comment: Also "And didn't want to take discussion about it", the moderator in question **clearly** told OP to go to meta and discuss it there, instead of polluting the comments on the question further. This is what meta is for. Also, a moderator included the deleted comments for transparency and context, and another moderator (yours truly) responded to the post. Please don't make accusations about the moderation team silencing and avoiding discussion, that's not only false, but actually pretty insulting.

Comment: @Madara A community shows its character in dealing with its minorities - yes, it sounds weird, but female users are a minority here. To state a specific need of a minority isn't relevant is an anti-pattern in this context. This is exactly the way minorities shouldn't be treated. They decide what is relevant to them, not the majority. SO should treat its female users with special sensitivity so that their number grows and a better community evolves.

Comment: @ftor Minorities should not be treated any differently (or demand any different treatment) than any other member of the community, that's what makes them a minority. I know that female users are a minority here. No, I don't think we need to be extra sensitive towards any particular population. Discrimination works both way. When you discriminate in favor of one population, you discriminate against everyone else. SO should treat its female users just like it treats any other members, with respect and professionalism to the person, not to the gender.

Comment: *“If you're going to remove all noise remove all gender-exclusive language as well. But that's not done. … here a moderator clearly removed gender-excluding language”* Eh? Anyway, we definitely try to remove unintentionally gender-exclusive noise! Feel free to edit it out whenever. I do.

Comment: @ftor With all due respect, no. No singling out, no special treatment, no quotas. Replacing one kind of discrimination with another doesn't solve anything

Comment: @ftor For any given member, the treatment is the same. Just because there are more for example men on SO, doesn't mean they're stronger. And then trying to facilitate options _especially_ for women would indeed be gender discrimination, just in the opposite way. Everyone should be considerate towards everyone, and minority members should not be treated different in _any way_

Comment: @ftor Any single member of the majority is not more powerful then any single member of the minority, at least here.