# Why does this user have 6 reputation points when there is no other question and no upvote?

Tags: discussion

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6847205/signup) have 6 reputation points on its profile when there is no upvote on his question and there are no other questions and answers present on his profile and also if there is any downvote after upvote so his reputation points must be 4 not 6.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39565892/how-list-all-invisible-pages-in-a-domain-website

> [image]
>   [image]

Comment: [How do you know it is a "he"?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334413/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

More than likely the member's question was downvoted first to -1, then upvoted back to 0.

Normally, it would be -2 for the downvote, but members can not go below the starting rep of 1, then the upvote pushed them up by 5 (as indicated in your image).

Comment: using the "view total votes without 1000 rep" addon in chrome i can confirm this. the question does have a +1/-1 to it. also in the user's rep history we can see that the upvote came ~30 minutes after the downvote

Answer (score 7):

When you expand the votes (You can do that once you reach 1000 rep), the picture becomes clearer:

> [image]

1. First, the user's question got one downvote, but because his rep was at 1, and because rep can't fall below 1, it had no effect.
2. Then the user's question got one upvote, which awarded +5 rep, as usual for questions.

Even without 1000 rep, the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39565892/timeline) for the user's question confirms this further:

> [image]